# How do I execute a string containing Python code in Python?

Tags: python, string, exec

How do I execute a string containing Python code in Python?

---

<sub>Editor's note: [**Never use `eval` (or `exec`) on data that could possibly come from outside the program in any form. It is a critical security risk. You allow the author of the data to run arbitrary code on your computer.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice) If you are here because you want to create multiple variables in your Python program following a pattern, **you almost certainly have an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info)**. Do not create those variables at all - instead, [use a list or dict appropriately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1373164).</sub>

Comment: The correct answer, of course, is almost always “don't!”.

Comment: For readers coming across this question: It's worth noting that if you want to show the code in the traceback, [you need to patch `linecache.cache`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47183305/file-string-traceback-with-line-preview).

Answer (score 85, accepted):

In the example a string is executed as code using the exec function.

```
import sys
import StringIO

# create file-like string to capture output
codeOut = StringIO.StringIO()
codeErr = StringIO.StringIO()

code = """
def f(x):
    x = x + 1
    return x

print 'This is my output.'
"""

# capture output and errors
sys.stdout = codeOut
sys.stderr = codeErr

exec code

# restore stdout and stderr
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__

print f(4)

s = codeErr.getvalue()

print "error:\n%s\n" % s

s = codeOut.getvalue()

print "output:\n%s" % s

codeOut.close()
codeErr.close()
```

Comment: swapping out stdout and stderr like that make me very nervous. this looks like it could cause huge security problems. is there a way around that?

Comment: @Narcolapser you should be mych more concerned with using `exec` at all (unless you _know_ the code string comes from a trusted source).

Answer (score 466):

For statements, use [`exec(string)`](https://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#exec) (Python 3) or [`exec string`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-exec-stmt) (Python 2):

```
>>> my_code = 'print("Hello world")'
>>> exec(my_code)
Hello world
```

When you need the value of an expression, use [`eval(string)`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval):

```
>>> x = eval("2+2")
>>> x
4
```

However, the first step should be to ask yourself if you really need to.  Executing code should generally be the position of last resort: It's slow, ugly and dangerous if it can contain user-entered code.  You should always look at alternatives first, such as higher order functions, to see if these can better meet your needs.

Comment: but how about the scope of the code executed by 'exec'? is it nested?

Comment: A common case where someone wants to use 'exec' is something like `if s=='foo': x.foo = 42 elif s=='bar': x.bar = 42` etc, which they may then write as `exec ("x.%s = 42" % s)`. For this common case (where you only need to access an object's attribute that is stored in a string), there is a much faster, cleaner and safer function `getattr`: just write `getattr(x, s) = 42` to mean the same thing.

Comment: How is exec any slower than the python interpreter?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR don't you mean `setattr(x, s, 42)`? I tried `getattr(x, 2) = 42` and it failed with `can't assign to function call: <string>, line 1`

Comment: @Tanner: Hmm. Yes indeed `setattr(x, s, 42)` is the right syntax. Surprised it took so long for that error to be caught. Anyway, the point is that `getattr` and `setattr` are an alternative to `exec` when all you want is to get an arbitrary member, looked up by string.

Comment: My usecase is allowing some debugging/admin access to a web service.

Comment: One legitimate use of the exec function I have found is when I define custom magics in iPython Notebook. The input to the magic function is a string representation of the code in the line or cell of the magic. After doing whatever "magic" the magic should do, you need to execute the code.

Comment: @CrisStringfellow slower because it has to recompile every time

Comment: I don't recommend using exec() function because it cannot change local variables, which could cause faults. Please see https://www.sololearn.com/Discuss/1336429/exec-doesn-t-work-with-local-variables-in-function-python f

Answer (score 40):

`eval` and `exec` are the correct solution, and they can be used in a *safer* manner.

As discussed in [Python's reference manual](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#exec) and clearly explained in [this](http://lybniz2.sourceforge.net/safeeval.html) tutorial, the `eval` and `exec` functions take two extra parameters that allow a user to specify what global and local functions and variables are available.

For example:

```
public_variable = 10

private_variable = 2

def public_function():
    return "public information"

def private_function():
    return "super sensitive information"

# make a list of safe functions
safe_list = ['public_variable', 'public_function']
safe_dict = dict([ (k, locals().get(k, None)) for k in safe_list ])
# add any needed builtins back in
safe_dict['len'] = len

>>> eval("public_variable+2", {"__builtins__" : None }, safe_dict)
12

>>> eval("private_variable+2", {"__builtins__" : None }, safe_dict)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'private_variable' is not defined

>>> exec("print \"'%s' has %i characters\" % (public_function(), len(public_function()))", {"__builtins__" : None}, safe_dict)
'public information' has 18 characters

>>> exec("print \"'%s' has %i characters\" % (private_function(), len(private_function()))", {"__builtins__" : None}, safe_dict)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'private_function' is not defined
```

In essence you are defining the namespace in which the code will be executed.

Comment: It is not possible to make eval safe:  [Eval really is dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html).  If you take code from me and eval it, I can segfault your Python program.  Game over.

Comment: @NedBatchelder: this is no more dangerous than anything. in your link `rm /rf` is mentioned. so should we say that bash is dangerous because we can also do that ? the only problem is elevation attacks. But we care not about this if the script is not a remote service (i.e. if it is just something executed by you).

Comment: @v.oddou I was responding to alan's statement, "eval and exec .. can be used in a safe manner."  This is false.  If someone said, "bash can be used in a safe manner," that would also be false.  Bash is dangerous.  It is a necessary danger, but dangerous nevertheless.  Claiming that eval can be made safe is simply wrong.

Comment: @NedBatchelder yes indeed. and the link you point to is good material. with power comes responsibility, so the point is simply to be aware of the potential power of eval. and if we decide that power=danger.

Comment: @NedBatchelder Many pieces of code written in Python can be dangerous as well, but why are you assuming that `eval` or `exec` are intended to be used as `exec(input("Type what you want"))`? There are many cases where a program may write a procedure or a function as a result of a computation; resulting functions will be as safe and as fast (once evaluated) as any other part of a good and well-written program. _An unsafe program containing `exec` is not more dangerous than an unsafe program doing the damage by itself as `exec` doesn't give any new privilege to the program._

Comment: @ThomasBaruchel again, my point is to counter the notion that eval or exec can be made safe.  In particular, this answer claims that controlling the globals and locals will make it possible to use them safely. That is false.  Any time you use exec and eval, you have to know precisely what code is being executed.  If you don't, then you are open to dangerous operations.

Answer (score 23):

Remember that from version 3 `exec` is a function!
so always use `exec(mystring)` instead of `exec mystring`.

Answer (score 16):

## Avoid `exec` and `eval`

### Using `exec` and `eval` in Python is highly frowned upon.

#### There are better alternatives

From the top answer (emphasis mine):

> For statements, use `exec`.
>
> When you need the value of an expression, use `eval`.
>
> However, the first step should be to ask yourself if you really need to. **Executing code should generally be the position of last resort**: It's slow, ugly and dangerous if it can contain user-entered code. You should always look at **alternatives first, such as higher order functions**, to see if these can better meet your needs.

From [Alternatives to exec/eval?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768195/alternatives-to-exec-eval)

> set and get values of variables with the names in strings
>
> [while `eval`] would work, it is generally not advised to use variable names bearing a meaning to the program itself.
>
> Instead, better use a dict.

#### It is not idiomatic

From http://lucumr.pocoo.org/2011/2/1/exec-in-python/ (emphasis mine)

> #### Python is not PHP
>
> Don't try to circumvent Python idioms because some other language does it differently. Namespaces are in Python for a reason and **just because it gives you the tool `exec` it does not mean you should use that tool.**

#### It is dangerous

From http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html (emphasis mine)

> So eval is not safe, even if you remove all the globals and the builtins!
>
> The problem with all of these **attempts to protect eval() is that they are blacklists**. They explicitly remove things that could be dangerous. That is a losing battle because **if there's just one item left off the list, you can attack the system**.
>
> So, can eval be made safe? Hard to say. At this point, my best guess is that you can't do any harm if you can't use any double underscores, so maybe if you exclude any string with double underscores you are safe. Maybe...

#### It is hard to read and understand

From http://stupidpythonideas.blogspot.it/2013/05/why-evalexec-is-bad.html (emphasis mine):

> First, **`exec` makes it harder to human beings to read your code**. In order to figure out what's happening, I don't just have to read your code, **I have to read your code, figure out what string it's going to generate, then read that virtual code.** So, if you're working on a team, or publishing open source software, or asking for help somewhere like StackOverflow, you're making it harder for other people to help you. And if there's any chance that you're going to be debugging or expanding on this code 6 months from now, you're making it harder for yourself directly.

Comment: "my best guess is that you can't do any harm if you can't use any double underscores" - You could construct a string containing double underscores, and then call eval that string.

Comment: good advice, unless you are writing a code generator, or job runner or similar ... which most people here are probably doing.

Comment: I have to import a relative path from a config-file (`cfg.yaml`): `reldir : ../my/dir/ `, and `reldir = cfg[reldir]`. However, as this python code shall run on both Windows and Linux, I need this to adjust to the different operating systems path dividers; either `\\ ` or `/`. So I use `reldir : os.path.join('..','my','dir')` in the config file.
But this only results in `reldir` being this literal string, not being evaluated, so I cannot open a file in `reldir`. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: Uhm, no.   These are highly pythonic. What do you think a REPL is?

Answer (score 15):

`eval()` is just for expressions, while `eval('x+1')` works, `eval('x=1')` won't work for example. In that case, it's better to use `exec`, or even better: try to find a better solution :)

Answer (score 14):

It's worth mentioning that `exec`'s brother exists as well, called `execfile`, if you want to call a Python file. That is sometimes good if you are working in a third party package which have terrible IDE's included and you want to code outside of their package.

**Example:**

`execfile('/path/to/source.py')`

**or:**

`exec(open("/path/to/source.py").read())`

Comment: "IDE" i.e. "text editor"? Don't you mean "API?

Answer (score 10):

You accomplish executing code using exec, as with the following IDLE session:

```
>>> kw = {}
>>> exec( "ret = 4" ) in kw
>>> kw['ret']

4
```

Comment: This doesn't work in normal python. At least not in python 3.

Answer (score 9):

As the others mentioned, it's "exec" ..

but, in case your code contains variables, you can use "global" to access it, also to prevent the compiler to raise the following error:

> NameError: name 'p_variable' is not defined

```
exec('p_variable = [1,2,3,4]')
global p_variable
print(p_variable)
```

Answer (score 6):

I tried quite a few things, but the only thing that worked was the following:

```py
temp_dict = {}
exec("temp_dict['val'] = 10") 
print(temp_dict['val'])
```

output:

`10`

Comment: After trying most of the above methods , this is the only one that worked. Gracias

Answer (score 5):

Use [eval](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html).

Comment: Eval() does not execute statements.

Answer (score 4):

Check out [eval](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval):

```
x = 1
print eval('x+1')
->2
```

Comment: Eval() does not execute statements.

Answer (score 1):

The most logical solution would be to use the built-in [eval()](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval) function .Another solution is to write that string to a temporary python file and execute it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok .. I know this isn't exactly an answer, but possibly a note for people looking at this as I was. I wanted to execute specific code for different users/customers but also wanted to avoid the exec/eval. I initially looked to storing the code in a database for each user and doing the above.

I ended up creating the files on the file system within a 'customer_filters' folder and using the 'imp' module, if no filter applied for that customer, it just carried on

```
import imp


def get_customer_module(customerName='default', name='filter'):
    lm = None
    try:
        module_name = customerName+"_"+name;
        m = imp.find_module(module_name, ['customer_filters'])
        lm = imp.load_module(module_name, m[0], m[1], m[2])
    except:
        ''
        #ignore, if no module is found, 
    return lm

m = get_customer_module(customerName, "filter")
if m is not None:
    m.apply_address_filter(myobj)
```

so customerName = "jj"
would execute apply_address_filter from the customer_filters\jj_filter.py file

Comment: How did you manage security? How do you know customers won't abuse this privilege?