# How do I create variable variables?

Tags: python, variable-variables

I know that some other languages, [such as PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), support a concept of "variable variable names" - that is, the contents of a string can be used as part of a variable name.

I heard that this is a bad idea in general, but I think it would solve some problems I have in my Python code.

Is it possible to do something like this in Python? What can go wrong?

---

<sub>If you are just trying to *look up an existing* variable by its name, see [How can I select a variable by (string) name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47496415). However, first consider whether you can reorganize the code to avoid that need, following the advice in this question.</sub>

Comment: it's the maintainance and debugging aspects that cause the horror. Imagine trying to find out where variable 'foo' changed when there's no place in your code where you actually change 'foo'. Imagine further that it's someone else's code that you have to maintain... OK, you can go to your happy place now.

Comment: A further pitfall that hasn't been mentioned so far is if such a dynamically-created variable has the same name as a variable used in your logic. You essentially open up your software as a hostage to the input it is given.

Comment: All the responses here assume you have access to the base variables you want to access dynamically by name, which is not always the case. I think the most general approach to reproduce the example behaviour in PHP is to use eval() like this:

var_name = 'foo'; bar = 5; output = eval(var_name)

Comment: You can modify your global and local variables by accessing the underlying dictionaries for them; it's a horrible idea from a maintenance perspective ... but it can be done via ***globals().update()*** and ***locals().update()*** (or by saving the dict reference from either of those and using it like any other dictionary).  **NOT RECOMMENDED** ... but you should know that it's possible.

Comment: @JimDennis actually, no it can't. Modifications to the dict returned by `locals` **will not affect local namespaces in CPython**. Which is another reason not to do it.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I had tried testing this in an IPython shell, but did so at the top level (where locals() behaves like globsls()).  Redoing that test within a nested code (within the definition of a function) does show that I can't modify locals() from within that.  As you say, the help for locals (3.7.6) does warn: **"NOTE: Whether or not updates to this dictionary will affect name lookups in
the local scope and vice-versa is *implementation dependent* and not
covered by any backwards compatibility guarantees."**

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47496415/ for the case of *accessing* variables by name. I established this as a canonical because lots of stuff was being closed to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437726, which gives awful advice. The new canonical parallels the advice given in this question - rework the data structure if at all possible.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18425225

Answer (score 440, accepted):

You can use [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) to accomplish this. Dictionaries are stores of keys and values.

```
>>> dct = {'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
>>> dct
{'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
>>> dct["y"]
2
```

You can use variable key names to achieve the effect of variable variables without the security risk.

```
>>> x = "spam"
>>> z = {x: "eggs"}
>>> z["spam"]
'eggs'
```

For cases where you're thinking of doing something like

```
var1 = 'foo'
var2 = 'bar'
var3 = 'baz'
...
```

a [list](https://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) may be more appropriate than a dict. A list represents an ordered sequence of objects, with integer indices:

```
lst = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz']
print(lst[1])           # prints bar, because indices start at 0
lst.append('potatoes')  # lst is now ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'potatoes']
```

For ordered sequences, lists are more convenient than dicts with integer keys, because lists support iteration in index order, [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation), `append`, and other operations that would require awkward key management with a dict.

Answer (score 117):

Use the built-in [`getattr`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#getattr) function to get an attribute on an object by name.  Modify the name as needed.

```
obj.spam = 'eggs'
name = 'spam'
getattr(obj, name)  # returns 'eggs'
```

Answer (score 95):

It's not a good idea. If you are accessing a global variable you can use [`globals()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#globals).

```
>>> a = 10
>>> globals()['a']
10
```

If you want to access a variable in the local scope you can use [`locals()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#locals), but you cannot assign values to the returned dict.

**A better solution** is to use `getattr` or store your variables in a dictionary and then access them by name.

Comment: ***locals().update({'new_local_var':'some local value'})*** works just fine for me in Python 3.7.6; so I'm not sure what you mean when you say you cannot assign values through it.

Comment: Given `x = "foo"` and `locals()["x"] = "bar"` using `print x` gives the output `bar` for Jython 2.5.2. This was tested with an On Demand Automation Script in [tag:maximo].

Comment: The documentation of [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) specifically says: "The contents of this dictionary should **not** be modified." (emphasis mine)

Comment: @JimDennis`locals()`` provides a dictionary *created to represent* local variables. Updating it does not guarantee to update the *actual* local variables. In modern Python implementations it's more like a picture (showing the content) in a nice frame (a high-level ``dict``) – drawing on the picture won't actually change the real thing.

Comment: @JimDennis: You're likely using it in a context where it's not actually local variables of a function. [In an actual function, the *real* locals are not changed](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/PyU1TSEtP19D04pLAQgqFGwV1P2DPN09/Rx9FNXBYjn5yYk5xRqaeqUFKYklqRoVtuqhAS6OIa4uiuqaYBUFRZl5JRoVyByYpmj1CvVYTS4usB3//wMA "Python 3 – Try It Online"). Sure, you can save off the result of `locals()` and read from/write to it, but it never changes the real locals, you're just getting a `dict` snapshot and modifying said `dict`. In the cases it works, it's not actually locals (at least on CPython).

Comment: The reason it doesn't work, at least on CPython, is that CPython allocates a fixed size array for locals, and the size of said array is determined when the function is defined, not when its run, and can't be changed (access to true locals doesn't even use the name; the name is replaced with the index into the array at function compile time). `locals()` returns a true `dict`; within a function, that `dict` is made by loading names and associated values in the array when you call `locals()`, it won't see future changes. If it changes, you're at global or class scope (which use `dict` scopes\).

Answer (score 84):

New coders sometimes write code like this:

```
my_calculator.button_0 = tkinter.Button(root, text=0)
my_calculator.button_1 = tkinter.Button(root, text=1)
my_calculator.button_2 = tkinter.Button(root, text=2)
...
```

The coder is then left with a pile of named variables, with a coding effort of O(*m* * *n*), where *m* is the number of named variables and *n* is the number of times that group of variables needs to be accessed (including creation). The more astute beginner observes that the only difference in each of those lines is a number that changes based on a rule, and decides to use a loop. However, they get stuck on how to dynamically create those variable names, and may try something like this:

```
for i in range(10):
    my_calculator.('button_%d' % i) = tkinter.Button(root, text=i)
```

They soon find that this does not work.

If the program requires arbitrary variable "names," a dictionary is the best choice, as explained in other answers. However, if you're simply trying to create many variables and you don't mind referring to them with a sequence of integers, you're probably looking for a `list`. This is particularly true if your data are homogeneous, such as daily temperature readings, weekly quiz scores, or a grid of graphical widgets.

This can be assembled as follows:

```
my_calculator.buttons = []
for i in range(10):
    my_calculator.buttons.append(tkinter.Button(root, text=i))
```

This `list` can also be created in one line with a comprehension:

```
my_calculator.buttons = [tkinter.Button(root, text=i) for i in range(10)]
```

The result in either case is a populated `list`, with the first element accessed with `my_calculator.buttons[0]`, the next with `my_calculator.buttons[1]`, and so on. The "base" variable name becomes the name of the `list` and the varying identifier is used to access it.

Finally, don't forget other data structures, such as the `set` - this is similar to a dictionary, except that each "name" doesn't have a value attached to it. If you simply need a "bag" of objects, this can be a great choice. Instead of something like this:

```
keyword_1 = 'apple'
keyword_2 = 'banana'

if query == keyword_1 or query == keyword_2:
    print('Match.')
```

You will have this:

```
keywords = {'apple', 'banana'}
if query in keywords:
    print('Match.')
```

Use a `list` for a sequence of similar objects, a `set` for an arbitrarily-ordered bag of objects, or a `dict` for a bag of names with associated values.

Answer (score 49):

Whenever you want to use variable variables, it's probably better to use a dictionary. So instead of writing

```
$foo = "bar"
$$foo = "baz"
```

you write

```
mydict = {}
foo = "bar"
mydict[foo] = "baz"
```

This way you won't accidentally overwrite previously existing variables (which is the security aspect) and you can have different "namespaces".

Answer (score 33):

Use `globals()` (disclaimer: this is a bad practice, but is the most straightforward answer to your question, please use other data structure as in the accepted answer).

You can actually assign variables to global scope dynamically, for instance, if you want 10 variables that can be accessed on a global scope `i_1`, `i_2` ... `i_10`:

```
for i in range(10):
    globals()['i_{}'.format(i)] = 'a'
```

This will assign 'a' to all of these 10 variables, of course you can change the value dynamically as well. All of these variables can be accessed now like other globally declared variable:

```
>>> i_5
'a'
```

Answer (score 19):

Instead of a dictionary you can also use [`namedtuple`](https://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) from the collections module, which makes access easier.

For example:

```
# using dictionary
variables = {}
variables["first"] = 34
variables["second"] = 45
print(variables["first"], variables["second"])

# using namedtuple
Variables = namedtuple('Variables', ['first', 'second'])
v = Variables(34, 45)
print(v.first, v.second)
```

Comment: Keep in mind `namedtuple`s are immutable so they're a bit different than simply dicts with dot notation. Having said that, both options promote good design principles and don't abuse the global namespace like half the answers in this thread do.

Answer (score 18):

The [`SimpleNamespace`](https://docs.python.org/library/types.html#types.SimpleNamespace) class could be used to create new attributes with `setattr`, or subclass `SimpleNamespace` and create your own function to add new attribute names (variables).

```
from types import SimpleNamespace

variables = {"b":"B","c":"C"}
a = SimpleNamespace(**variables)
setattr(a,"g","G")
a.g = "G+"
something = a.a
```

Answer (score 15):

If you don't want to use any object, you can still use `setattr()` inside your current module:

```
import sys
current_module = module = sys.modules[__name__]  # i.e the "file" where your code is written
setattr(current_module, 'variable_name', 15)  # 15 is the value you assign to the var
print(variable_name)  # >>> 15, created from a string
```

Comment: This does not work with `__dict__` variable however. I wonder if there is a general mechanism to create *any* global variable dynamically.

Comment: `globals()` can do this

Answer (score 14):

### Variable variables in Python

```
"""
<?php
$a = 'hello';
$e = 'wow'
?>
<?php
$$a = 'world';
?>
<?php
echo "$a ${$a}\n";
echo "$a ${$a[1]}\n";
?>
<?php
echo "$a $hello";
?>
"""

a = 'hello'  #<?php $a = 'hello'; ?>
e = 'wow'   #<?php $e = 'wow'; ?>
vars()[a] = 'world' #<?php $$a = 'world'; ?>
print(a, vars()[a]) #<?php echo "$a ${$a}\n"; ?>
print(a, vars()[vars()['a'][1]]) #<?php echo "$a ${$a[1]}\n"; ?>
print(a, hello) #<?php echo "$a $hello"; ?>
```

Output:

```
hello world
hello wow
hello world
```

---

#### Using globals(), locals(), or vars() will produce the same results

```
#<?php $a = 'hello'; ?>
#<?php $e = 'wow'; ?>
#<?php $$a = 'world'; ?>
#<?php echo "$a ${$a}\n"; ?>
#<?php echo "$a ${$a[1]}\n"; ?>
#<?php echo "$a $hello"; ?>

print('locals():\n')
a = 'hello'
e = 'wow'
locals()[a] = 'world'
print(a, locals()[a])
print(a, locals()[locals()['a'][1]])
print(a, hello)

print('\n\nglobals():\n')
a = 'hello'
e = 'wow'
globals()[a] = 'world'
print(a, globals()[a])
print(a, globals()[globals()['a'][1]])
print(a, hello)
```

Output:

```
locals():

hello world
hello wow
hello world


globals():

hello world
hello wow
hello world
```

---

#### Bonus (creating variables from strings)

```
# Python 2.7.16 (default, Jul 13 2019, 16:01:51)
# [GCC 8.3.0] on linux2
```

##### Creating variables and unpacking tuple:

```
g = globals()
listB = []
for i in range(10):
    g["num%s" % i] = i ** 10
    listB.append("num{0}".format(i))

def printNum():
    print "Printing num0 to num9:"
    for i in range(10):
        print "num%s = " % i, 
        print g["num%s" % i]

printNum()

listA = []
for i in range(10):
    listA.append(i)

listA = tuple(listA)
print listA, '"Tuple to unpack"'

listB = str(str(listB).strip("[]").replace("'", "") + " = listA")

print listB

exec listB

printNum()
```

Output:

```
Printing num0 to num9:
num0 =  0
num1 =  1
num2 =  1024
num3 =  59049
num4 =  1048576
num5 =  9765625
num6 =  60466176
num7 =  282475249
num8 =  1073741824
num9 =  3486784401
(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9) "Tuple to unpack"
num0, num1, num2, num3, num4, num5, num6, num7, num8, num9 = listA
Printing num0 to num9:
num0 =  0
num1 =  1
num2 =  2
num3 =  3
num4 =  4
num5 =  5
num6 =  6
num7 =  7
num8 =  8
num9 =  9
```

Comment: The `vars` and `locals` dicts can't be modified inside a function. And [mutable global state is bad](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/148108/352138) except maybe in the simplest scripts. So this only has limited usefulness.

Answer (score 13):

You have to use [`globals()` built in method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals)  to achieve that behaviour:

```
def var_of_var(k, v):
    globals()[k] = v

print variable_name # NameError: name 'variable_name' is not defined
some_name = 'variable_name'
globals()[some_name] = 123
print(variable_name) # 123

some_name = 'variable_name2'
var_of_var(some_name, 456)
print(variable_name2) # 456
```

Answer (score 9):

I'm answering the question [How to get the value of a variable given its name in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9437726/how-to-get-the-value-of-a-variable-given-its-name-in-a-string)
which is closed as a duplicate with a link to this question. (Editor's note: It is now closed as a duplicate of [How can I select a variable by (string) name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47496415/how-can-i-select-a-variable-by-string-name))

---

If the variables in question are part of an object (part of a class for example) then some useful functions to achieve exactly that are `hasattr`, `getattr`, and `setattr`.

So for example you can have:

```
class Variables(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.foo = "initial_variable"

    def create_new_var(self, name, value):
        setattr(self, name, value)

    def get_var(self, name):
        if hasattr(self, name):
            return getattr(self, name)
        else:
            raise "Class does not have a variable named: " + name
```

Then you can do:

```
>>> v = Variables()
>>> v.get_var("foo")
'initial_variable'
```

```
>>> v.create_new_var(v.foo, "is actually not initial")
>>> v.initial_variable
'is actually not initial'
```

Comment: This raises a string, which is not allowed. `TypeError: exceptions must derive from BaseException`. But why bother with `hasattr()` and `raise` when you could just do `getattr()` unconditionally and let it raise `AttributeError` for you?

Answer (score 7):

I have tried both in python 3.7.3, you can use either globals() or vars()

```
>>> food #Error
>>> milkshake #Error
>>> food="bread"
>>> drink="milkshake"
>>> globals()[food] = "strawberry flavor"
>>> vars()[drink] = "chocolate flavor"
>>> bread
'strawberry flavor'
>>> milkshake
'chocolate flavor'
>>> globals()[drink]
'chocolate flavor'
>>> vars()[food]
'strawberry flavor'
```

Reference:
https://www.daniweb.com/programming/software-development/threads/111526/setting-a-string-as-a-variable-name#post548936

Answer (score 4):

The consensus is to use a dictionary for this - see the other answers. This is a good idea for most cases, however, there are many aspects arising from this:

- you'll yourself be responsible for this dictionary, including garbage collection (of in-dict variables) etc.
- there's either no locality or globality for variable variables, it depends on the globality of the dictionary
- if you want to rename a variable name, you'll have to do it manually
- however, you are much more flexible, e.g.

  - you can decide to overwrite existing variables or  ...
  - ... choose to implement const variables
  - to raise an exception on overwriting for different types
  - etc.

That said, I've implemented a [variable variables manager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/python-vvm/)-class which provides some of the above ideas. It works for python 2 and 3.

You'd use [the class](https://sourceforge.net/p/python-vvm/code/ci/master/tree/variableVariablesManager.py) like this:

```
from variableVariablesManager import VariableVariablesManager

myVars = VariableVariablesManager()
myVars['test'] = 25
print(myVars['test'])

# define a const variable
myVars.defineConstVariable('myconst', 13)
try:
    myVars['myconst'] = 14 # <- this raises an error, since 'myconst' must not be changed
    print("not allowed")
except AttributeError as e:
    pass

# rename a variable
myVars.renameVariable('myconst', 'myconstOther')

# preserve locality
def testLocalVar():
    myVars = VariableVariablesManager()
    myVars['test'] = 13
    print("inside function myVars['test']:", myVars['test'])
testLocalVar()
print("outside function myVars['test']:", myVars['test'])

# define a global variable
myVars.defineGlobalVariable('globalVar', 12)
def testGlobalVar():
    myVars = VariableVariablesManager()
    print("inside function myVars['globalVar']:", myVars['globalVar'])
    myVars['globalVar'] = 13
    print("inside function myVars['globalVar'] (having been changed):", myVars['globalVar'])
testGlobalVar()
print("outside function myVars['globalVar']:", myVars['globalVar'])
```

If you wish to allow overwriting of variables with the same type only:

```
myVars = VariableVariablesManager(enforceSameTypeOnOverride = True)
myVars['test'] = 25
myVars['test'] = "Cat" # <- raises Exception (different type on overwriting)
```

Answer (score 2):

Any set of variables can also be wrapped up in a class. 
"Variable" variables may be added to the class instance during runtime by directly accessing the built-in dictionary through __dict__ attribute.

The following code defines Variables class, which adds variables (in this case attributes) to its instance during the construction. Variable names are taken from a specified list (which, for example, could have been generated by program code):

```
# some list of variable names
L = ['a', 'b', 'c']

class Variables:
    def __init__(self, L):
        for item in L:
            self.__dict__[item] = 100

v = Variables(L)
print(v.a, v.b, v.c)
#will produce 100 100 100
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be extremely risky...
but you can use exec():

```
a = 'b=5'
exec(a)
c = b*2
print (c)
```

Result:
10

Comment: This won't work inside a function. It's essentially equivalent to the safer `locals()['b'] = 5` (which also won't work in a function).

Comment: @benrg Do you know how to get around Rubens failed suggestion because I'm stuck with the same situation? I have a file containing a long list of variable assignments as a collective string. I need to turn them into python assignments but eval() and exec() both fails.

Answer (score 0):

The **setattr()** method sets the value of the specified attribute of the specified object.

**Syntax goes like this –**

```
setattr(object, name, value)
Example –

setattr(self,id,123)
```

which is equivalent to `self.id = 123`

As you might have observed, setattr() expects an object to be passed along with the value to generate/modify a new attribute.

We can use setattr() with a workaround to be able to use within modules. Here’ how –

```
import sys
x = "pikachu"
value = 46
thismodule = sys.modules[__name__]
setattr(thismodule, x, value)
print(pikachu)
```

Comment: It's easier to use `globals()`.

Answer (score -1):

**TL;DR**:  Consider using `eval()`

I found this page because I was looking to do some simple template processing with python string functions (short of including a full blown template engine).  I was searching for how to set local variables, and that's how I got here.

My problem began with a simple template:

```
Hello, {name}
```

The way I populated this template was this way:

```
def populate(template,variables):
    return template.format(**variables)
```

And so this would work:

```
values = {
  'name' : 'Stack Overflow' 
}
my_template = "Hello, {name}"
print( populate( my_template , values ) )

# output
Hello, Stack Overflow
```

But then things went south fast.  I tried a new template where I only wanted the first word:

Now my template was this:  `"Hello, {name.split()[0]}"` and this code got an error.

```
values['name'] = "Stack Overflow"
my_template = "Hello, {name.split()[0]}"
print( populate( my_template , values ) 
# output (well, stderr)
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'split()'. Did you mean: 'split'?
```

And then I learned that the format function doesn't work the way I want it.  You can't pass arbitrary code to it.  You need to pass it formatting stuff.  And so I tried a different solution.  I coded `populate` to use `eval` and an f-string instead of `format`.  An f-string (unlike format) allows for python code in the curly brace interpolation.  So an f-string like this `f"Hello, {name.split()[0]}" does work.  Let's just see the code for this small part (so you don't have to leave this post to figure out f-string):

```
name = "Stack Overflow"
print(f"Hello, {name.split()[0]}")
# Output:
Hello, Stack
```

Now I just had to use an f-string.  So I used `eval`.  My new populate is this:

```
def populate(template,variables):
    return eval(f'f"{template}"')
```

But when I ran the program again, I got this error:

```
NameError: name 'name' is not defined
```

I should point out that an f-string is able to populate the string with any global or local variable in scope.  To fix my issue, I could change my template to  `"Hello, {variables['name']}"` since  `variables` is definitely in scope.  This is really bad approach because now the template writer has to know about a the `variables` dictionary.  Rather, I want to make every key available in the `variables` dictionary available to the template author, as I had before with `format(**variables)`.

To solve my problem, I wanted to set local variables based on the content of the `variables` dictionary passed to the `populate()` function.

I tried this:

```
locals() = variables
```

And that didn't work:

```
    locals() = variables
    ^^^^^^^^
SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call here. Maybe you meant '==' instead of '='?
```

And then I tried this and this worked:

```
def populate(template,variables):
    for k,v in variables.items():
      locals()[k] = v
    return eval(f'f"{template}"')


values = {
  'name' : 'Stack Overflow'
}
my_template = "Hello, {name.split()[0]}"
print( populate( my_template , values ) )
```

And so the first take away is that you can create local variables *in a function* (or globals for that matter) by setting a key value pair in the locals() dictionary.

In the case of `eval`, the second and third parameters allow you to pass in local and global variables, and so you could simplify the populate function to just this:

```
def populate(template,variables):
    return eval(f'f"{template}"',variables)
```

The above is how I used `eval` to do f-string population (or simplistic template evaluation).  But `eval` can also be used to provide variable variables.