# How to load a module from code in a string?

Tags: python

I have some code in the form of a string and would like to make a module out of it without writing to disk.

When I try using imp and a StringIO object to do this, I get:

```
>>> imp.load_source('my_module', '', StringIO('print "hello world"'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: load_source() argument 3 must be file, not instance
>>> imp.load_module('my_module', StringIO('print "hello world"'), '', ('', '', 0))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: load_module arg#2 should be a file or None
```

How can I create the module without having an actual file?  Alternatively, how can I wrap a StringIO in a file without writing to disk?

**UPDATE:**

NOTE: This issue is also a problem in python3.

The code I'm trying to load is only partially trusted.  I've gone through it with ast and determined that it doesn't import anything or do anything I don't like, but I don't trust it enough to run it when I have local variables running around that could get modified, and I don't trust my own code to stay out of the way of the code I'm trying to import.

I created an empty module that only contains the following:

```
def load(code):
    # Delete all local variables
    globals()['code'] = code
    del locals()['code']

    # Run the code
    exec(globals()['code'])

    # Delete any global variables we've added
    del globals()['load']
    del globals()['code']

    # Copy k so we can use it
    if 'k' in locals():
        globals()['k'] = locals()['k']
        del locals()['k']

    # Copy the rest of the variables
    for k in locals().keys():
        globals()[k] = locals()[k]
```

Then you can import `mymodule` and call `mymodule.load(code)`.  This works for me because I've ensured that the code I'm loading does not use `globals`.  Also, the `global` keyword is only a parser directive and can't refer to anything outside of the exec.

This really is way too much work to `import` the module without writing to disk, but if you ever want to do this, I believe it's the best way.

Comment: If you don't trust the code, do not load it. Its terribly hard to make a python interpreter really safe (e.g. there are some ways to patch the bytecode of some different stack frame once you have access to a code object). So if this is just to prevent errors it might work, as a security thing it is probably a bad idea.

Comment: I've used ast pretty extensively to ensure it can't do anything dangerous.  There may be holes, but I'm pretty sure that the holes can be patched if discovered.

Comment: `del locals()['code']` does nothing, as the `locals()` dictionary is but a proxy, a reflection of the actual locals. Just use `del code` if you must delete a reference. Not that I am sure why you are doing this at all. Why the whole dance with `globals()` and `locals()` *in the first place*?

Comment: @ConleyOwens: I'm pretty sure they can't be patched. Python's dynamic nature leaves you wide open. Execute untrusted code *in a virtual machine without network access* that you then wipe and restart from a trusted image.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Here is how to import a string as a module (**Python 2.x**):

```
import sys,imp

my_code = 'a = 5'
mymodule = imp.new_module('mymodule')
exec my_code in mymodule.__dict__
```

In **Python 3**, exec is a function, so this should work:

```
import sys,imp

my_code = 'a = 5'
mymodule = imp.new_module('mymodule')
exec(my_code, mymodule.__dict__)
```

Now access the module attributes (and functions, classes etc) as:

```
print(mymodule.a)
>>> 5
```

To ignore any next attempt to import, add the module to `sys`:

```
sys.modules['mymodule'] = mymodule
```

Comment: Great tip! Very small and nice code for [Reflection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_programming%29)

Comment: This causes `import` statements in `my_code` to evaluate to `None`.

Comment: @Kimvais: I can't reproduce that. Importing works *just fine*.

Comment: Python 2 `exec` can be used like a function *too*. The Python 3 version works unchanged in Python 2.

Comment: The `imp.new_module` function is marked as deprecated since at least Python 3.4.

Comment: `imp.new_module` has been deprecated for a few years. The same behavior can be achieved with [`types.ModuleType('mymodule')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/types.html#types.ModuleType).

Answer (score 31):

`imp.new_module` is [deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3/library/imp.html#imp.new_module) since python 3.4, but it still works as of python 3.9

`imp.new_module` was replaced with `importlib.util.module_from_spec`

> [importlib.util.module_from_spec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.module_from_spec)
> is preferred over using `types.ModuleType` to create a new module as
> spec is used to set as many import-controlled **attributes on the module**
> as possible.
>
> [importlib.util.spec_from_loader](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.spec_from_loader)
> uses available loader APIs, such as `InspectLoader.is_package()`, to
> fill in any missing information on the spec.

these module attributes are `__builtins__` `__doc__` `__loader__` `__name__` `__package__` `__spec__`

```py
import sys, importlib.util

def import_module_from_string(name: str, source: str):
  """
  Import module from source string.
  Example use:
  import_module_from_string("m", "f = lambda: print('hello')")
  m.f()
  """
  spec = importlib.util.spec_from_loader(name, loader=None)
  module = importlib.util.module_from_spec(spec)
  exec(source, module.__dict__)
  sys.modules[name] = module
  globals()[name] = module


# demo

# note: "if True:" allows to indent the source string
import_module_from_string('hello_module', '''if True:
  def hello():
    print('hello')
''')

hello_module.hello()
```

Comment: What if i would like to reload the module when the code string change? Is it safe to simply load it again?

Answer (score 7):

You could simply create a Module object and stuff it into sys.modules and put your code inside.

Something like:

```
import sys
from types import ModuleType
mod = ModuleType('mymodule')
sys.modules['mymodule'] = mod
exec(mycode, mod.__dict__)
```

Comment: `mod` doesn't seem to be a mapping object and `eval` can only handle expressions (i.e., it can't handle `x = 1`) so that really limits it.

Comment: Thanks, updating the answer with the `exec`.

Answer (score 4):

If the code for the module is in a string, you can forgo using `StringIO` and use it directly with `exec`, as illustrated below with a file named `dynmodule.py`.
Works in Python 2 & 3.

```
from __future__ import print_function

class _DynamicModule(object):
    def load(self, code):
        execdict = {'__builtins__': None}  # optional, to increase safety
        exec(code, execdict)
        keys = execdict.get(
            '__all__',  # use __all__ attribute if defined
            # else all non-private attributes
            (key for key in execdict if not key.startswith('_')))
        for key in keys:
            setattr(self, key, execdict[key])

# replace this module object in sys.modules with empty _DynamicModule instance
# see Stack Overflow question:
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5365562/why-is-the-value-of-name-changing-after-assignment-to-sys-modules-name
import sys as _sys
_ref, _sys.modules[__name__] = _sys.modules[__name__], _DynamicModule()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import dynmodule  # name of this module
    import textwrap  # for more readable code formatting in sample string

    # string to be loaded can come from anywhere or be generated on-the-fly
    module_code = textwrap.dedent("""\
        foo, bar, baz = 5, 8, 2

        def func():
            return foo*bar + baz

        __all__ = 'foo', 'bar', 'func'  # 'baz' not included
        """)

    dynmodule.load(module_code)  # defines module's contents

    print('dynmodule.foo:', dynmodule.foo)
    try:
        print('dynmodule.baz:', dynmodule.baz)
    except AttributeError:
        print('no dynmodule.baz attribute was defined')
    else:
        print('Error: there should be no dynmodule.baz module attribute')
    print('dynmodule.func() returned:', dynmodule.func())
```

Output:

```
dynmodule.foo: 5
no dynmodule.baz attribute was defined
dynmodule.func() returned: 42
```

Setting the `'__builtins__'` entry to `None` in the `execdict` dictionary prevents the code from directly executing **any** built-in functions, like `__import__`, and so makes running it safer. You can ease that restriction by selectively adding things to it you feel are OK and/or required.

It's also possible to add your own predefined utilities and attributes which you'd like made available to the code thereby creating a custom execution context for it to run in. That sort of thing can be useful for implementing a "plug-in" or other user-extensible architecture.

Answer (score -1):

The [documentation for `imp.load_source`](http://docs.python.org/library/imp.html#imp.load_source) says (my emphasis):

> The file argument is the source file, open for reading as text, from the beginning. **It must currently be a real file object, not a user-defined class emulating a file.**

... so you may be out of luck with this method, I'm afraid.

Perhaps [`eval`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval) would be enough for you in this case?

This sounds like a rather surprising requirement, though - it might help if you add some more to your question about the problem you're really trying to solve.

Answer (score -1):

you could use `exec` or `eval` to execute python code as a string. see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python), [here](http://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/ref/exec.html) and [here](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#eval)