# python always create a file name "c", why ? (with cs=imp.load_source('cs','',f) function)

Tags: python, python-2.7

I would like to use a txt file with configure variable for my python code.And I saw and copied following code from web to my python.

```
def getVarFromFile(filename):
  import imp 
  f = open(filename)
  global cs
  cs = imp.load_source('cs', '', f)
  f.close()
```

The strange thing is whenever I run the python code, I got a file named "c" in my directory, and it stores lots of strange characters like:

mò
;€-Rc

Why there comes this "c" file ? How can I get rid of that ? Thanks

----adding info-----
I made the call by

```
getVarFromFile('config/cs.txt')
```

And my cs.txt looks like:

```
var1 = 'abc'
var2 = 'h'
var3 = '2'
var4 = '1'
```

And I use the data like:

var2 = int(cs.var2)

And by my debugging, once I put the

```
sys.exit()
```

Before

```
cs = imp.load_source('cs', '', f)
```

There is no such c file is generated. While I put exit after that line, there is the file named "c" generated.

So it must relate to that function

Comment: What is the value of `filename` when you call that function?

Comment: @jbaiter just added some more info above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to give a more sensible value for the `pathname` parameter.

`imp.load_source(name, pathname, file)` is used to load a sourcefile. As part of that it will compile the sourcefile to bytecode and write the compiled code out to a `.pyc` file. The name of the `.pyc` file I think it gets by putting `c` on the end of the `pathname` you supplied.

If you don't want the compile caching, then simply read the file and create your own module. See [Load module from string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362771/load-module-from-string-in-python) for a way to do this:

```
import sys,imp

my_code = 'a = 5'
mymodule = imp.new_module('mymodule')
exec my_code in mymodule.__dict__
```

Combined with your original code would be something like (untested):

```
def getVarFromFile(filename):
  import imp 
  with open(filename) as f:
      global cs
      cs = imp.new_module('cs')
      exec(f.read(), cs.__dict__)
```