# Child calls to parent which calls back to child ... or not

Tags: python, inheritance, operator-overloading, python-datetime

```
from datetime import timedelta

class A:
    def __abs__(self):
        return -self

class B1(A):
    def __neg__(self):
        return 'neg from B1'

class B2(timedelta):
    def __neg__(self):
        return 'neg from B2'

print(abs(B1()))     # neg from B1
print(abs(B2(-1)))   # 1 day, 0:00:00
```

Why does the first print call use the overridden method, but the second one doesn't?  I don't understand. The second case appears to also call `-self` in the python implementation [here](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/32ee7b9d58c9/Lib/datetime.py#l523).

Comment: Because `-self` uses `__neg__`? Why would `B2`?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: It’s the intention of the `-1` passed to `B2`, I suppose: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/aa8ea3a6be22c92e774df90c6a6ee697915ca8ec/Lib/datetime.py#L525

Comment: @minitech: don't confuse the Python reference implementation with the C implementation. :-)

Comment: Yeah, I think OP is confusing `__neg__` and `__sub__`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I think that’s what wim’s doing, rather.

Comment: (https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/aa8ea3a6be22c92e774df90c6a6ee697915ca8ec/Modules/_datetimemodule.c#L1768-L1782)

Comment: @LennartRegebro: uhm, no, I don't think so.

Comment: Oh, minitech hit the nail on the head.  If you can move that stuff into an answer instead of a comment I could accept it ..

Comment: So, the "reference" python implementation has some different behaviours from the C implementation?  Which is the correct behaviour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure I am missing something here, but there is *no reason* for `B2` to ever call `__neg__`. The `timedelta` baseclass certainly won't use it.

`B1().__abs__()` uses `-self`, which triggers the `self.__neg__()` call, but `B2` has no such operator applied to it.

Note that the [`datetime.py` Python implementation](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5a9901c21213/Lib/datetime.py#l514) isn't involved here; that code is there for systems that cannot, for some reason, run the [C implementation of the same](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5a9901c21213/Modules/_datetimemodule.c#l1762):

```c
static PyObject *
delta_abs(PyDateTime_Delta *self)
{
    PyObject *result;

    assert(GET_TD_MICROSECONDS(self) >= 0);
    assert(GET_TD_SECONDS(self) >= 0);

    if (GET_TD_DAYS(self) < 0)
        result = delta_negative(self);
    else
        result = delta_positive(self);

    return result;
}
```

where [`delta_negative`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/5a9901c21213/Modules/_datetimemodule.c#l1741) is the native implementation for the `__neg__` hook; the code never considers subclasses here.

Comment: I think the presumption is that `timedelta` will require `__neg__` to convert the negative input to positive. But it seems likely that it negates the constituent parts instead.

Comment: Can I trick my system into using the python implementation instead of the C implementation?

Comment: @wim: It'd take re-running the module without the last few lines. Load the `datetime.py` file into a string, remove the lines from `try: import _datetime` onwards, use [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362771/load-module-from-string-in-python) to create a replacement module object and stuff that into `sys.modules['datetime']`. Super hacky.

Comment: You are right.  I tried your "hack" and saw the output that I was initially expecting (`neg from B1`;`neg from B2`)