# executing python code from string loaded into a module

Tags: python, python-3.x, module

I found the following [code snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362771/load-module-from-string-in-python) that I can't seem to make work for my scenario (or any scenario at all):

```
def load(code):
    # Delete all local variables
    globals()['code'] = code
    del locals()['code']

    # Run the code
    exec(globals()['code'])

    # Delete any global variables we've added
    del globals()['load']
    del globals()['code']

    # Copy k so we can use it
    if 'k' in locals():
        globals()['k'] = locals()['k']
        del locals()['k']

    # Copy the rest of the variables
    for k in locals().keys():
        globals()[k] = locals()[k]
```

I created a file called "dynamic_module" and put this code in it, which I then used to try to execute the following code which is a placeholder for some dynamically created string I would like to execute.

```
import random
import datetime


class MyClass(object):
    def main(self, a, b):
        r = random.Random(datetime.datetime.now().microsecond)
        a = r.randint(a, b)
        return a
```

Then I tried executing the following:

```
import dynamic_module
dynamic_module.load(code_string)
return_value = dynamic_module.MyClass().main(1,100)
```

When this runs it should return a random number between 1 and 100.  However, I can't seem to get the initial snippet I found to work for even the simplest of code strings.  I think part of my confusion in doing this is that I may misunderstand how globals and locals work and therefore how to properly fix the problems I'm encountering.  I need the code string to use its own imports and variables and not have access to the ones where it is being run from, which is the reason I am going through this somewhat over-complicated method.

Comment: `exec()` takes `globals` and `locals` dictionaries. Just pass in empty ones, or pass in a new module object dictionary. That's what the accepted answer does.

Comment: This is code I copied directly from the link I provided.  Part of my problem is I don't understand this code completely.  Which is why I can't make it work for my scenario.

Comment: The code is utter nonsense, I'm afraid. It was written by someone who doesn't understand how exec works.

Comment: I've transferred my critique of the code to the other post.

Comment: So do you know of any code that I could replace it with to achieve my desired result?  This level of Python is a little above my current skill level I'm afraid, but I really want to learn how to do this.

Comment: Just use the accepted answer there instead, where they use a blank `module` object and pass in the globals dictionary to `exec()`.

Comment: Yes, the accepted answer worked.  Now I'm not sure if I should delete this entire question or not.  Thoughts?

Comment: Ah, I've written an answer now, which will makes it impossible for you to delete this yourself now. Provided the other answer doesn't get a vote, if I delete my answer you can self-delete. If you really want to, that's what I can do.

Comment: OTOH, having an answer to your question means anyone else finding that code and wondering what to do now will know they should avoid that.

Comment: Thanks for providing your comments as an answer.  Accepted, and your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not be using the code you found. It is has several big problems, not least that most of it doesn't actually do anything (`locals()` is a proxy, deleting from it has no effect on the actual locals, it puts any code you execute in the same shared globals, etc.)

Use the *accepted answer* in that post instead; recast as a function that becomes:

```
import sys, imp

def load_module_from_string(code, name='dynamic_module')
    module = imp.new_module(name)
    exec(code, mymodule.__dict__)
    return module
```

then just use that:

```
dynamic_module = load_module_from_string(code_string)
return_value = dynamic_module.MyClass().main(1, 100)
```

The function produces a new, clean module object.

Answer (score 0):

In general, this is not how you should dynamically import and use external modules. You should be using `__import__` within your function to do this. Here's a simple example that worked for me:

```
plt = __import__('matplotlib.pyplot', fromlist = ['plt'])
plt.plot(np.arange(5), np.arange(5))
plt.show()
```

I imagine that for your specific application (loading from code string) it would be much easier to save the dynamically generated code string to a file (in a folder containing an `__init__.py` file) and then to call it using `__import__`. Then you could access all variables and functions of the code as parts of the imported module.

Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: They are creating a module *from a string containing code*, not a file on disk, which is what you are importing.

Comment: I know, that's why I suggested saving the string to a file and then reload it with `__import__`. May not be the ideal solution he's looking for, but I think that this way would be a lot more understandable for anyone else who happens to read the code.

Comment: The linked post has much better answers though. `exec()` works fine for that case, provided you give it a better `globals` target, which is what the accepted answer does.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your last post before making my comment. I should've taken a look before writing.