# Calling a particular function for every module in a python directory

Tags: python, file, import, module

None of the answers on stack overflow have helped me with this problem: 
[Load module from string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362771/load-module-from-string-in-python)

My file structure is as follows: 
-run.py
-/boards
    -Brd1.py
    -Brd2.py
    -Brd3.py

What I am trying to accomplish is to call the "run" function for every module in the boards directory. Each module has this "run" function. Here is my code in run.py:

```
import os
import sys,imp
import inspect

for item in os.listdir("boards"):
    if item.startswith("Brd") and item.endswith(".py"):
        curr_module = imp.new_module(item)
        curr_module.run()
```

This is the error I get:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run'

However, when I explicitly do something like this:

```
from boards import Brd1

Brd1.run()
```

It works perfectly.
Interestingly enough, the code:

```
import os
import sys,imp
import inspect

for item in os.listdir("boards"):
    if item.startswith("Brd") and item.endswith(".py"):
        curr_module = imp.new_module(item)
        print dir(curr_module)
```

just prints: 
['__ doc __ ', ' __ name __ ', '__ package __ ']

Is there anyway to do what I am trying to accomplish? Am I going about this the right away?

Comment: "None of the answers on stack overflow have helped me with this problem" doesn't really help us. What questions and answers did you look at? How did they not help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not working for you because as abarnert pointed out, you're only loading an empty module. Also, looking at your file structure, you need to insert the path name of the boards folder:

```
sys.path.insert(0, './boards')
```

What you're attempting can be solved by simply using the python documentation for the import internals: https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.get_suffixes

I just tested it and this code does exactly what you're asking for:

```
for item in os.listdir("boards"):
    if item.startswith("Brd") and item.endswith(".py"):
        name = os.path.splitext(item)[0]
        fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module(name)
        with open(pathname) as f:
            curr_module = imp.load_module(name, fp, pathname, description)
            curr_module.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're not doing anything to load the modules, you're just creating and running empty modules.

```
curr_module = imp.new_module(item)
curr_module.run()
```

From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#imp.new_module) says:

> `imp.new_module`(*name*)
>
> Return a new empty module object called name. This object is not inserted in sys.modules.

So, this is effectively the same as if you'd written this:

```
curr_module = types.ModuleType(item)
curr_module.run()
```

The reason you get `['__ doc __ ', ' __ name __ ', '__ package __ ']` (although I'm pretty sure you actually get `['__doc__ ', '__name__', '__package__']` without all those extra spaces) is that those attributes exist even on an empty module.

---

The example code that you copied this from is trying to do something completely different. The whole point of that question is how to create a module out of a string of source code, instead of the normal way. Which you do (in 2.x) by creating a new empty module, then doing an `exec` against that module's globals. The `exec` is the reason the module ends up not being empty, and you're not doing anything similar.

---

You're also giving the module an invalid name, like `Brd1.py` instead of `Brd1`.

---

If you want to actually load the modules, look at the [Examples](https://docs.python.org/2/library/imp.html#examples):

```
fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module(name)
curr_module = imp.load_module(name, fp, pathname, description)
# …
```

Of course you don't want to load it by normal search, but by pathname. You could pass a `path` argument to `find_module`:

```
name = os.path.splitext(item)[0]
fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module(name, 'boards')
```

… or just load it directly:

```
name = os.path.splitext(item)[0]
pathname = os.path.join("boards", item)
desc = [s for s in imp.get_suffixes if s[0] == '.py']
with open(pathname) as f:
    curr_module = imp.load_module(name, f, pathname, desc)
```

---

You might also want to put the module in `sys.modules`. Or you might not. (The example doesn't, because it's simulating the effects of the `__import__` function.) If so:

```
sys.modules[name] = curr_module
```

---

You also might want to do the `sys.modules` check, as in the example. If you do the check, trying to import the same file twice will use the cached version the second time, as if you'd done a normal `import`; if you don't, it will be similar to calling `reload`:

```
try:
    curr_module = sys.modules[name]
except KeyError:
    # the logic above to find and load curr_module
```

Comment: This doesn't work. I get an ImportError: No module named Brd1

Comment: @kaaazemian "I get an ImportError" isn't something that can be debugged. Which of the three options above did you try? What does your code look like? Where did the exception come from?