# python create and register module via compile function

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a Python program that registers multiple importable modules while still being a single file.

I have a simple python program called `import_module` ... it's intended to define a module called `foo` whose implementation resides in a string literal.

In the example below, `compile` is called before `foo` is imported, but the compiled code object is simply discarded. What do I need to do in order to associate it to the name `foo` so that import foo will work?

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

compile(
'''
def hello():
    print("hello")
''',
'foo',
'exec'
)

import foo
foo.hello()
```

When run, this program produces the error:

```
./import_module 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./import_module", line 12, in <module>
    import foo
ImportError: No module named foo
Exit 1
```

I'd like it to print `hello`, but am not sure what to do with the code object to register it with the import system.

Ideally, I'd like to do this in such a way that it works independently of version. I'm trying to write a single script that can be run on systems where `python` is either `python2` or 3+.

If no such version independent-method of registering modules exists, I'm okay with inspecting the version info and doing something different depending on the version.

Comment: Good question, but this may depend on the Python version you're using. Could you specify the version, perhaps by adding the appropriate tag? (Or if you want an answer that covers all versions in common use, it would be useful to say that explicitly.)

Comment: Are you looking for `exec`? You probably want to pass the compiled code object to `exec`, or just directly `exec` the string.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't think `exec` exposes the functionality I want. I'm looking to write something kind of like `waf` where there's a specially named executable that sets up a Python environment with a bunch of libraries and then transfers control to a user-provided script. The waf executable is also a self-contained file, but it's implemented as a self-extracting archive (I think).

Comment: Do you mean you want use it like `executable user-script.py`, and then it can setup a bunch of libraries? I think you can read `user-script.py` and `exec` it in your `executable`.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5362771/2988730

Comment: @Sraw yes, but then functions that I implement in `executable` that are meant to be internal would be visible to the user script. And have the API exposed by `executable` be separated out into modules.

Comment: Create an empty module, run your code in its namespace, add it to sys.modules. No need for the import statement.

Comment: @GregoryNisbet I am unfamiliar with `waf`. But if your goal is to hide internals, I would say spare the effort in Python. Or if you really want an executable that can obscure internals, use a C-extension, or better yet, Cython. You can automate all that using `subprocess` at the interpreter level.