# Convert string to variable in python

Tags: python

How to convert `a=b=2` string into `a=2, b=2` (actual assignments) in python?

There are some python parsers which give output for expressions like `2+3+4`.

But how to use `a=b=2` string into variable as `a=2 b=2`?

Comment: Do you want `a,b = 2`?

Comment: The big question is *why*? Because the answer kinda depends.

Comment: You can use `eval` function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
s = 'a=b=2'
exec(s)    #executes the string as a python command
```

And you are done

```
print(a)
2
print(b)
2
```

Refer to this discussion for more info:
[How do I execute a string containing Python code in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python)

Comment: thanks for all responses. One more thing how to solve this b=("a=2)+4"