# WLST execute stored variable "connect()" statement

Tags: python, weblogic, wlst

So, I am passing a environment variable from bash to python;

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import os

#connect("weblogic", "weblogic", url=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx)
os.environ['bash_variable']
```

via wlst.sh I can print exported bash_variable, but how do I execute stored variable?  Basically, I am trying to remove the original connect statement and pass a variable that has said information.  Thanks

Comment: You want to use `bash_variable` as the `url` parameter?

Comment: No, I want to replace connect("weblogic", etc with what is stored in the bash_variable - which IS a complete connect statement.  That's the reason I need to execute that stored variable.

Comment: Means, `bash_variable` contains something like `connect("weblogic", "weblogic", url="192.168.1.1:7001")`?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: `exec` should work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/701813/1611055. However, when I did something similar, I was passing username, password and url as environment variables and passed them to `connect`. With `exec` you can execute any python code stored in your variable, which could be a security issue

Answer (score 1):

Question though, why wouldn't you called the script with the variable as an argument and use sys.argv[] ?

By example something like this.

```
import os
import sys
import traceback
from java.io import *
from java.lang import *




wlDomain = sys.argv[1]
wlDomPath = sys.argv[2]
wlNMHost = sys.argv[3]
wlNMPort = sys.argv[4]
wlDPath="%s/%s" %(wlDomPath,wlDomain)
wlNMprop="/apps/bea/wls/scripts/.shadow/NM.prop"

try:
    print "Connection to Node Manager"
    print ""
    loadProperties(wlNMprop)
    nmConnect(username=NMuser,password=NMpass,host=wlNMHost,port=wlNMPort,domainName=wlDomain,domainDir=wlDPath,mType='ssl',verbose='true')
except:
    print "Fatal Error : No Connection to Node Manager"
    exit()

print "Connected to Node Manager"
```

The NM.prop file is a 600 file with the username/password for the NM.

EDIT :

So from what I understand you want to do something like this :

```
URLS = ['t3s://Host1:Port1','t3s://Host2:Port2','t3s://Host3:Port3']
for urls in URLS:
    connect('somebody','password',urls)
    {bunch of commands}
    disconnect()
```

And the values of the list URLS would be define by the environment.

The way I see it you have 3 choices :

1. Have 1 script per environment, more or less identical save for the URLS list
2. Have 1 script but with a conditionnal branching on sys.argv[1] (the environment as a parameter) and create the list there.
3. Have 1 script which use a parameter file for each environment according to the environment. Each parameter file containing the list in question.

Something like that :

```
propENV = sys.argv[1]
propPath = "/path1/path2"
propFile = "%s/%s" %(propPath,propENV)

loadProperties(propFile)
```

I would probably use the properties file option myself as it is more flexible from an operational standpoint...at least IMHO.

Comment: The reason I was utilizing bash was because the url field was assigned in a assoc array.  User input would provide environment, and that key would provide more than one value (depending on environment)- meaning there were multiple urls that required connecting to via WLST.  I need to remove bash from the equation and use python to create a for loop and run a set of commands for each URL provided.

Comment: Well you could load a properties file based on the environment provided by users and containing list of URL (and other informations).

Comment: How exactly would that work with a properties file?  The scenario is something along these lines;  wlst.sh ./script.py [var] [var] [var] [env]  wlst.sh sets up the environment and the script.py connects directly to a managed server and executes commands contained within script.py.  The issue is that [env] contains multiple MS - up to 10 in some environments.  The bash script is not really appropriate because it would run the command on one URL at a time, exit WLST and re-issue the entire command referenced above for each MS.