# Setting line attributes programmatically in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, attributes

I have a module for standardized plotting, and would like to pass it a tuple with line attributes for each line in the plot.  Ideally it would work like the code fragment below...where I've abstracted the tuple as a simple string for simplicity.  This generates an error because it doesn't know how to parse my string.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=range(10)
y=range(10)
myStyle = "'b-',linewidth=2.0"
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x,y,myStyle)

ValueError: Unrecognized character ' in format string
```

Can that be implemented in another way? Or..is there an alternate solution (akin to Matlab) where I assign the line a handle and access its line attributes in a loop like this?

```
myStyl = (["color=b","linestyle='-'","linewidth=1.5"],  )
lh = plt.plot(x,y)
for ii in range(len(myStyle[0]))
    plt.setp(lh,myStyle[0][ii])          #<----what goes here
```

Comment: like this :`myStyle = 'b-',"2.0"` , `plt.plot(x,y,myStyle[0],linewidth=float(myStyle[1]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use, for example, `eval`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x=range(10)
y=range(10)
myStyle = "'b-',linewidth=2.0"
plt.figure(1)
eval("plt.plot(x,y,"+myStyle+")")
plt.show()
```

But be careful with this. Check a question like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python) to be more informed about this option.

Comment: @armattia: indeed this is a good solution.  I finally found documentation on setting line attributes but upon testing it appears that the keywords must be explicit. .  [Documentation is here.](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/set_and_get.html)