# How can I convert string to source code in python?

Tags: python, string, command, eval

As you see, ifinner is a string, so if I just write after if, always will be true. What can i do, to concert it to source code?

```
    x=2
    ifinner = "x==3"
    if ifinner:
        print("Yeah")
    else:
        print("It works!")
```

Comment: You should parse the string and handle the different conditional options

Comment: Any particular reason you're not doing `ifinner = x == 3`, which works in your example?

Comment: In the real situation, where is the string coming from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I execute a string containing Python code in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use [`eval()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#eval) function to evaluate Python source code.

Quoting the documentation:

> eval(expression, globals=None, locals=None)
>
> The arguments are a string and optional *globals* and *locals*. If provided, globals must be a dictionary. If provided, *locals* can be any mapping object.

Comment: but never use `eval` on any string that you didn't create yourself (or from a trusted source)!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
exec ("%s == 3" % x)
```

For detailed info, read the documentation of eval and exec in python 2.x/3.x.
A similar question was asked previously.Here's the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

I think eval does not work with strings like this

```
str_ = "import matplotlib"
```

in that case you might have to open a separate file, write the string and then execute it.

Comment: you can use `exec` for this string. For example try the following
`exec( "import matplotlib.pyplot as mp" ); mp.plot([1,2,3],[-1,0,1]); mp.show()`
no error. But you are right that `eval` is not suitable for this string.