# I am looking to preform a calculation with elements from a list in python 3.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am looking to make a program where the user enters a sum eg. 5 + 6 - 7, and my program recognise's it and gives the answer eg 4. So far my program will take the input, recoginises the numbers and operations, and assigns them to a list, however, I am not sure how to take the numbers and operators and calculate them. Does anyone have anything that could help??

Here is my code

```
s = "5 + 6 - 7" #User input placeholder

q = s.split() #splits the input into a list with an element for every character(not spaces)
print(q)

n = [] #numbers in user input
a = [] #actions/operations that the user inputs

print(q)


for x in range(0, len(q)):
    if q[x].isdigit(): #determines whether an element is a digit
        q[x] = int(q[x]) #str to int
        n.append(q[x]) #adds it to the n list
        print(n)
    else:
        a.append(q[x]) #adds an operation to the a list
        print(a)

answer = n[0], a[0], n[1], a[1], n[2]

print("Operations are: ", a)
print("Numbers are: ", n)
print("Answer is: ", answer)
```

Comment: This question was already asked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert string to source code in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43878504/how-can-i-convert-string-to-source-code-in-python)

Comment: Neither of those are useful if your goal is to attempt to implement a simple parser by yourself, instead of just calculating what the user has given you. In that case using a library is the sane way to do it, but it won't let you learn how you could do something fragile, but similar.

Answer (score 3):

[The `operator` module gives you direct access](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/operator.html) to all the standard operators in Python as functions.

You can assign each operator function to its textual representation and use that to look up the operators:

```
ops = {'+': operator.add, '-': operator.sub}
```

Running through your numbers and operators, you pick two arguments off your list for each operation and apply it, before pushing the result back in the list:

```
print("Operations are: ", a)
print("Numbers are: ", n)

for operation in a:
    arg_a = n.pop(0)
    arg_b = n.pop(0)

    result = ops[operation](arg_a, arg_b)
    n.insert(0, result)

print("Answer is: ", n[0])
```

The element that's left in your `n` list is the answer to the calculation as requested. This assumes that the calculation is well-formed.

Answer (score -1):

In such case you can use `eval()` which recognizes the expression and calculates the output.

for example,

```
s = "5 + 6 - 7"
print(eval(s))
```

output:

```
4
```

It is the simplest thing you can do.Hope this helps you!