# Turn string to a function in python

Tags: python

Is there a way to convert a string value to a function? If this simply isn't doable with python, please let me know.

For example, I would like to convert this string:

```
'''
def greet(name):
    return f'Hello, {name}'
'''
```

to this function:

```
def greet(name):
    return f'Hello, {name}'
```

---

In a program, the example might look like:

```
function_string = '''
def greet(name):
    return f'Hello, {name}'
'''

def str_to_func(string):
    # Function body...

str_to_func(function_string)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert string to source code in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43878504/how-can-i-convert-string-to-source-code-in-python)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec

Comment: Does `eval` work for turning strings to functions?

Comment: A `def` statement is not an expression. You would need to use `exec`, not `eval`. Use with caution.

Comment: How would I use `exec`?

Comment: Oh okay, nevermind. I understand. Thank you @khelwood !

Comment: I'm just curious as to why? It could be an XY problem, are you maybe importing what's otherwise python script, but is being read as strings?

Comment: Except in really specific cases best to avoid evals or execs they are a big security risk.  If it’s your code you can import it on demand, given its dotted path.  [importlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html)can help with that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here's an example use [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec)

```
function_string = '''
def greet(name):
    return f'Hello, {name}'

print(greet('john'))
'''

exec(function_string)
```

output :

```
Hello, john
```