# Is there a way to convert a string to code?

Tags: python, string

If I have a string like this
`"value = 10"`
how would I make it so the value is equal to 10

Comment: Hey there, this might help answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43878504/how-can-i-convert-string-to-source-code-in-python

Comment: @Anurag, I believe he wants `10` being assigned to the variable `value`

Comment: Well then just do `value = int("value = 10".split(' ')[-1])`

Comment: Btw `eval()` method doesn't work in this case It throws error...you can also use `value=int("value = 10"[8:])`

Comment: You're right @Anurag, I'll remove my answer... I would have sweared that worked though...

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in `exec` method:

```
exec("value = 10")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> exec("value = 10")
>>> print(value)
10
>>> exec("value = 11")
>>> print(value)
11
```