# transform a list of datetimes in a pandas column to list of strings

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following `pandas` dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

foo = pd.DataFrame({'id': [1,2], 'time' :['[datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 20, 14, 29, 51), datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 20, 14, 46, 8)]', '[datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 20, 15, 0, 44), datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 20, 16, 13, 42)]']})
foo

   id   time
0   1   [datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 20, 14, 29, 51), datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 20, 14, 46, 8)]
1   2   [datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 20, 15, 0, 44), datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 20, 16, 13, 42)]
```

I would like to transform each element of the lists in the `time` column to a string with the format `'%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'`

I know I can do this:

```
t = datetime.datetime(2021, 10, 20, 14, 29, 51)
t.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S')
```

to yield the value `'2021/10/20 14:29:51'`,

but I do not know how to do this operation for every **string** element of each list in the `time` column.

Any help ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert string to source code in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43878504/how-can-i-convert-string-to-source-code-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use list comprehension inside `apply` after converting string lists to actual lists with `eval`:

```
foo.time.apply(lambda str_list: [item.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S') for item in eval(str_list)])
```

Comment: Sorry, my input dataframe was wrong, I corrected it. For the corrected one this solution does not work :(

Comment: I've updated the answer for the new dataframe

Comment: I was putting the `eval` to the wrong place. I need a walk ;) tnx

Answer (score 0):

You can separate the list into rows first with `explode` and then use the dt accessor in pandas:

```
(foo
 .explode('time')
 .assign(time=lambda x: x.time.dt.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S'))
)
```