# Is it possible to execute string as code in scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

So for spark sql you have do something like this:

```
val query = s"select *from table...."
val temp = sqlContext.sql(query)
```

Is there anything similar to this for just regular spark code? Like in python they have this `exec(string)` function that take string and run it as code.
This is the link: [Click Me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python)

Comment: what do you mean with "regular spark code"?

Comment: @RaphaelRoth I imagine the OP means Scala code.

Comment: I feel that executing Scala code from a string isn't the best of ideas, it feels like the OP might be attempting an elaborate workaround for something which has a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

[Gatling](http://gatling.io/) application is doing a similar trick, they allow you to write an arbitrary Scala code for load testing and then run it with their framework.

As far as I remember they basically write Scala code into a file, prepend/append it with something like:

```
class MyClass {
  def foo() = {
  // Code goes here
  }
}
```

and execute Scala compiler to compile this code and then load this code as a regular class.