# Running a python script that is stored in a database with pycharm? How to?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, mariadb, heidisql

I have MariaDB/HeidiSQL instance and in it I have a table which contains the values (1, print('Hello World!'). The first number is just an Id.

So my question is can I access this Python script with my pycharm and run it?

Is it possible to store python scripts into a DB and the run them in pycharm, with some sort of query?

Comment: Possibly related: [How do I execute a string containing Python code in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python). Get what you need from the database and then execute it that way.

Comment: Can you please provide a valid usecase for storing your code in a database?

Comment: Probably an answer in here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/701802/1531971

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I execute a string containing Python code in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Just write a python script which connects to your database using a client and fetch the target script as string.
How to execute a string in python as code is explained in the question
[How do I execute a string containing Python code in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python)

Comment: What I did was this:                                                                                              cur = db.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT Script FROM Game")
db.commit()
result =  str(cur.fetchone())
mycode = result[2:23]
exec(mycode)

db.close()