# Python Mechanize set cookie

Tags: python, cookies, mechanize

This below code works.

```
cookiejar =cookielib.LWPCookieJar()
br.set_cookiejar(cookiejar)

c0 = cookielib.Cookie(version=0, name='_mobile_sess', value='BAh7ByIKZmxhc2hJQzonQWN0aW9uQ29udHJvbGxlcjo6Rmxhc2g6OkZsYXNoSGFzaHsABjoKQHVzZWR7ADoQX2NzcmZfdG9rZW4iLTY4YWYxODc5ZmVlNTRhMDM4YzUwN2VjMmNiMWJkMjZlMTIxNDViNWM%3D--a18dca22d18735ebb9c4f91f595bae999e138f5e', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='.twitter.com', domain_specified=True, domain_initial_dot=True, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=True, expires=1531884528, discard=False, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={'HTTPOnly': None}, rfc2109=False)

cookiejar.set_cookie(c0)
```

However, due to some reason, I have to to store c0 as a string.
So actually, c0 is a unicode string

```
c0 = u"cookielib.Cookie(version=0, name='_mobile_sess', value='BAh7ByIKZmxhc2hJQzonQWN0aW9uQ29udHJvbGxlcjo6Rmxhc2g6OkZsYXNoSGFzaHsABjoKQHVzZWR7ADoQX2NzcmZfdG9rZW4iLTY4YWYxODc5ZmVlNTRhMDM4YzUwN2VjMmNiMWJkMjZlMTIxNDViNWM%3D--a18dca22d18735ebb9c4f91f595bae999e138f5e', port=None, port_specified=False, domain='.twitter.com', domain_specified=True, domain_initial_dot=True, path='/', path_specified=True, secure=True, expires=1531884528, discard=False, comment=None, comment_url=None, rest={'HTTPOnly': None}, rfc2109=False)"
```

so that

```
cookiejar.set_cookie(c0)
```

return error

```
if cookie.domain not in c: c[cookie.domain] = {}

AttributeError: 'Text' object has no attribute 'domain'
```

How do I fix this problem? How do I convert unicode string c0 to "something" that `cookiejar.set_cookie(c0)` can accept?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#grammar-token-exec_stmt) statement to execute the string stored in `c0`

```
exec "c0 = " + c0
```

For example:

```
>>> exec u"print('hello')"
hello
```

See: [How do I execute a string containing Python code in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python)

Comment: c0= exec(c0)
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Thank you. You saved my life!