# Python interpret input as math function

Tags: python, python-3.x

How do you turn a string gathered from input into an actual function? For example,

```
    >>>function = input("Enter a function: ")
    >>>Enter a function: "sin(t)"
```

And then I'd be able to use the entered function. Is there a library to parse through the string and return a math function like so?

Comment: you might just be stuck doing a long `if/elif/else` series for each operation you want to cover.

Comment: Parsing is nontrivial. No standard library does what you want to do. Doubtless people have written modules to do this, but asking for library recommendations is off-topic on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. It's really hard to tell what exactly you're asking for here. Please [edit] your question to include some expected input/output and any attempt you've made to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `exec`

```
>>> import math
>>> t=45
>>> exec('s=math.sin(t)')
>>> s
0.8509035245341184
>>>
```

Or if you just want the function

```
>>> exec('f=math.sin')
>>> 
>>> f(45)
0.8509035245341184
>>>
```

Comment: Link to similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python

Comment: What if the "string gathered from input" is malicious? In any event -- this doesn't address the question of how to turn the string into a function. Saying that the user can enter Python code which is then evaluated by `exec` in unlikely to be what OP had in mind.