# Is there a way to let the user supply Python code that will run in my program?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm quite new to this so apologies in advance if this is a silly question. I'm trying to build a simple module which takes a Pandas dataframe and a set of instructions (in some text format) as an input, and converts this dataframe to a nested JSON representation of the data.

My plan was to essentially leave a section of the code blank and let the user supply the code (instructions) for how to do this conversion. I'm sure this is not a good way to solve the problem, and I'd happily take pointer on how it should be done as well, but is there a way to let the user insert a section of code into the code itself, and then execute the program?

Comment: you *could* use python eval to execute arbitrarily any code but it is probably a bad idea h(ow would you protect yourself from malicious code?) It would be better to have an idea of what sort of data manipulations you want to support and build a mini DSL around that.

Comment: Python functions can accept other functions as arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [exec](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_exec.asp) function.

If you need some control over the validation of the instructions, maybe it's better to do as @will says. Take a look at this similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python)