# How to convert string like "tensor([13., 16.])" to a tensor

Tags: python, matplotlib

I read a data from file txt which contain info about location like this:
"...
Location: tensor([13., 16.])
Location: tensor([11., 1.])
...
"
My question is how to convert it in real tensor to make a plot. 
I am reading data like this:

```py
for line in file:
     M_l = re.search(r"Location: (.*)", line)
     location = M_l.group(1)
     plt.plot(location, 'r+')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Try the following snippet. You have to extract the actual lists (which are between parenthesis) that corresponds to your tensors, which are in `string` format. So convert this string list to python list using `ast`. Then use `tf.convert_to_tensor` to convert to a tensor (only if necessary?). If you do want to convert to a tensor, then you have to run the tensor inside a session and get the value and plot. If you do not require to generate a tensor, you can just plot the list without using tensorflow sessions.

```py
import tensorflow as tf
import re
import ast


file = open("test.txt","r")
for line in file:
    M_l = re.search(r"Location: (.*)", line)
    location = M_l.group(1)
    location=ast.literal_eval(re.search('\(([^)]+)', location).group(1))

    l=tf.convert_to_tensor(location, dtype=tf.float32)

    with tf.Session() as sess:

        plt.plot(sess.run(l), 'r+')
```