# How to convert a string to python code in python?

Tags: python

If I have a string containing some code in a python file. I want to run the code in the string, for example:

```
program = "for i in range(100):\n\tprint(i)"
eval(program)
```

However, I'm pretty sure eval only works for mathematical operations, so it throws a syntax error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    eval(program)
  File "<string>", line 1
    for i in range(100):
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Is there a way in python of running code contained in a string?

Comment: Strictly speaking, the answer to the question in the title is to use `compile`; `exec` produces the code *and* executes it.

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, `eval()` only evaluates *expressions*, not statements or suites (which comprise full Python programs).

You're looking for the [`exec()` function](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functions.html#exec).

```
exec("for i in range(100):\n\tprint(i)")
```

However, do remember you usually don't need `eval()` or `exec()`, and especially you'll *never* want to `exec()` or `eval()` user input.

Comment: this is clearly a duplicate. you've been around long enough to know to mark it as one...

Answer (score 0):

[Use the `exec()` function.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec)

```
program = "for i in range(100):\n\tprint(i)"
exec(program)
```