# Execute hashed python code (base64, sha256 or whatever)

Tags: python, hash, base64, sha256

in this case I want to execute my hashed python code.

but the problem is, how can I do the hash and then decode the hash that I did earlier. then execute the python code that was hashed on the python compiler.

in example i have simple code :

```
print('Hello World!')
```

decode code to plain text :

```
>> import base64
>> encoded = b'cHJpbnQoIkhlbGxvIFdvcmxkISIp' 
>> decoded = base64.b64decode(encoded)
>> decoded
>> b'print("Hello World!")'
```

the decoded will execute the code as plain text. 
so, how to get the compiler to run it as python code ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I execute a string containing Python code in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python)

Comment: Base64 != hash. Hashing is meant to be one-way. Once something is hashed, it's very very very difficult to get back the original from the hash. The word you should be using is "encoding/decoding". SHA256 is a hash. And you wouldn't be able to get back the original string from it (not without a lot of work anyway).

Comment: @rdas so base64 is not hash. i should learn more, thank you for knowledge