# Alternatives to Exec and Eval when Importing a file path as string in Python

Tags: python, eval, delimiter

I have to use a config-file `cfg.yml`:

```
---
paths:
    reldir : ../my/dir
```

In Python, I run:

```
with open('cfg.yml', 'r') as config_file:
    cfg = yaml.load(config_file)
```

and my goal is to do something with some files in the directory `reldir`, via the Python file. The above works well.

---

However, this Python program must be able to run on Windows and Linux. If I am not mistaken, they use different path delimiters, `/` and `\\`. Thus, I want to make the `reldir` in the config file more robust:

```
---
paths:
    reldir : os.path.join('..','my','dir').
```

If my understanding is correct, this will combine these folder names with the correct delimiter, depending on where the Python program is executed.

However, this doesn't work, and `print(reldir)` outputs `os.path.join('..','my','dir')` instead of `../my/dir`. I.e., it is taking the string literally without evaluating the `os.path.join` function.

I experimented with `exec()` and `eval()`, but first, I could not get it to run anyway; and second, I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python) that I shouldn't use these.

How should I best proceed?

Comment: Note `yaml.load` is just as bad as `exec` and `eval`.  Use `yaml.safe_load`.

Answer (score 1):

Usually "/" works for Windows as well. You can just try "../my/dir"