# How on python to change the name of the launched instruction using the input parameter of the function?

Tags: python

How on python to change the name of the launched instruction using the input parameter of the function? How to do this without using if and else? The idea is to make a statement something like .format() for strings. See an example of an idea below.

```
def run_module(file, module_name):
    .
    .
    .
    res = object.module_name(file, param2, param3, ...)
    .
    .
    .
    return
```

object - an entity from the library, there is no possibility to change.
I would be grateful for any constructive advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to what Cibin said, you're using `module_name` as the name of a function, but the name of the parameter makes it seem as if it's the name of a module instead.

Assuming `module_name` refers to the name of a function to invoke, an alternative to the `exec()` is using `getattr()`, which is probably a bit cheaper/faster.

For example:

```
def run_module(file, module_name):
    .
    .
    .
    res = getattr(object, module_name)(file, param2, param3, ...)
    .
    .
    .
    return
```

The `getattr()` method returns the function `module_name` of the object `object`, and then you can invoke that returned function like any normal function, and pass in the required parameters.

Comment: Thank! This is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, are you sure `module_name` is a module and not a function?

You could make it a string and then execute that like this:

```py
def run_module(file, module_name):
    .
    .
    commandString = "res = object." + module_name + "(file, param2, param3, ...)"
    exec(commandString)
    .
    .
    return
```

This might be a related question you'd like to look into:
1. [How do I execute a string containing Python code in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python)