# Convert to executable values in dictionary python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, pyarrow

I have one dictionary named column_types with values as below.

```
column_types = {'A': 'pa.int32()',
                'B': 'pa.string()'
               }
```

I want to pass the dictionary to pyarrow read csv function as below

```
from pyarrow import csv
table = csv.read_csv(file_name,
                     convert_options=csv.ConvertOptions(column_types=column_types)
                     )
```

But it is giving an error because values in dictionary is a string.
The below statement will work without any issues.

```
from pyarrow import csv
table = csv.read_csv(file_name, convert_options=csv.ConvertOptions(column_types = {
                  'A':pa.int32(),
                  'B':pa.string()
               }))
```

How can I change dictionary values to executable statements and pass it into the csv.ConvertOptions ?

Comment: Do not pass code in a string and execute it. Instead pass a function object and call it.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python This answer here may help

Comment: To expand on @alaniwi's comment, to do so, remove the `()`.`column_types = {'A': pa.int32}`, etc..

Comment: @DivyangVashi this is NOT a case where he wants to use the `exec` function.

Comment: @Axe319 I can't remove braces. Because int32 and string are function of pyarrow.

Comment: @diwakarg removing them turns them into a function object. The `()` on a function calls them and executes them and I'm assuming in this case returns an `int` and a `string`. if you want to hand it the type, you would hand it the object.

Comment: Take the builtin `str` for example. If you want to check if something is of type `str` you would use `isinstance(some_string, str)`.  `isinstance(some_string, str())` would throw an error.

Comment: @Axe319 Please share sample code. Difficult to understand what are you saying

Comment: @Axe319 I am generating this column types programmatically. ```column_types['A'] = 'pa.'+datatype+'()'``` by iterating over for loop

Comment: `pa.int32` is a function. Putting `pa.int32()` in your code will call the function and return an int. In your example the class `ConvertOptions` is looking for the type of column. Not an int. So you would hand it `pa.int32`. I used the string example because it's easy to understand. `test = str()` assigns an empty string to `test`. `test = str` assigns the function `str` to `test`.

Comment: If you are doing that you can just as easily assign function objects like `column_types['A'] = datatype` in a loop. just have `datatype = pa.int32` and so on. There's no need to convert to a string and then back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways that worked for me you can use both of them however I would recommend the second one as the first one uses `eval()` and using it is risky in user input cases. If you are not using input string given by user you can use method 1 too.

1) USING `eval()`

```
import pyarrow as pa

column_types={}

column_types['A'] = 'pa.'+'string'+'()'
column_types['B'] = 'pa.'+'int32'+'()'

final_col_types={key:eval(val) for key,val in column_types.items()} # calling eval() to parse each string as a function and creating a new dict containing 'col':function()

from pyarrow import csv
table = csv.read_csv(filename,convert_options=csv.ConvertOptions(column_types=final_col_types))
print(table)
```

2) By creating a master dictionary `dict_dtypes` that contains the callable function name for a particular string. And further using `dict_dtypes` to map the string to its corresponding function.

```
import pyarrow as pa

column_types={}

column_types['A'] = 'pa.'+'string'+'()'
column_types['B'] = 'pa.'+'int32'+'()'

dict_dtypes={'pa.string()':pa.string(),'pa.int32()':pa.int32()} # master dict containing callable function for a string
final_col_types={key:dict_dtypes[val] for key,val in column_types.items() } # final column_types dictionary created after mapping master dict and the column_types dict

from pyarrow import csv
table = csv.read_csv(filename,convert_options=csv.ConvertOptions(column_types=final_col_types))
print(table)
```

Comment: The problem is I am generating this column types programmatically. Like below ```column_types['A'] = 'pa.'+datatype+'()'``` by iterating over for loop

Comment: Ok sorry for that. I have updated the answer. Check and tell me if that works for you.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't we use something like this:

```
column_types = {'A': pa.int32(),
                'B': pa.string()}

table = csv.read_csv(file_name, 
                     convert_options=csv.ConvertOptions(column_types=column_types))
```

Comment: The problem is I am generating this column types programmatically. Like below ```column_types['A'] = 'pa.'+datatype+'()'``` by iterating over for loop