# Executing a string as python code and storing output + errors

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing a small IDE for myself in Python at the moment and want to execute the text of my editor as Python code. I get the text of my editor as a string. I want to execute the code, save the ouput
& errors in string-variables (`o` and `e`) and then I render the output in my IDE.

It works fine as long as I don't have any errors (`my_code`). Once I execute code containing an error (`my_code_with_error` - commented below), it seems as if the code is not returning and "silently" crashing. In fact I even get `Process finished with exit code 0` in Pycharm - probably because I switched `sys.stdout` for my own `StringIO` instance.

How can I execute the code-string, even if it has errors and then save the error / normal output in a variable as a String?

```
import sys
from io import StringIO

# create file-like string to capture output
codeOut = StringIO()
codeErr = StringIO()
print("Start")

my_code = """
print("Hello World!")
"""

my_code_with_error = """
print("Hello world!")
print(avfsd)  # error -> printing a variable that does not exist.
"""

print("Executing code...")
# capture output and errors
sys.stdout = codeOut
sys.stderr = codeErr

exec(my_code )  # this works fine
# exec(my_code_with_error)  # as soon as there is an error, it crashes silently.

# restore stdout and stderr
sys.stdout = sys.__stdout__
sys.stderr = sys.__stderr__
print("Finished code execution.")

e = codeErr.getvalue()
o = codeOut.getvalue()
print("Error: " + e)
print("Output: " + o)

codeOut.close()
codeErr.close()
```

PS: There was a really old question from 2009 where I got some of my code, but can't find any more recent questions concerning this topic. ([How do I execute a string containing Python code in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python?answertab=votes#tab-top))

Comment: You likely want to spawn a child process, so you can have better control over the input and output channels.

Comment: Take a look at the [code module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/code.html#module-code) in the stdlib (which is what IDLE uses). It's mostly written in pure python, so [the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/code.py) should be instructive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try surrounding the execution code in a try/except block.

```
try:
    exec(my_code)
except:
    print("Unexpected error:", sys.exc_info()[0])
    raise
```

Comment: This works great! I love that I even get the class of the error with sys.exc_info. I have one problem though - if I have a correct `print` statement in front of my error-line, I don't get the output of that one, I only get the error back. Is it possible to get the "correct" output leading up to the error as well?

Comment: You can place the string and the error output in 2 seperate print statements. `print("Unexpected error: ")` `print(sys.exc_info()[0])`

Comment: Ah, I think you misunderstood me - I edited my question: The `my_code_with_error`  contains two statements. The first one is working, the second one throws the error. If I would execute the two statements in Pycharm, I first get the output `Hello world!` and then it throws an error. In your solution, I only get the error from sys.exc_info()

Comment: If you want the error-free code to run before the exception is thrown, you would have to split the commands into separate strings and call `try: exec()` for each string.

Comment: I just realized your code already does what I want... sorry, my bad. The problem was EOL-errors (no quote-ending) are thrown before anything is executed so I didn't realize it is what I need. Thanks :D

Answer (score 2):

You can do that by catching the exceptions :

```
try:
    exec(my_code_with_error)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

Raymond posted a similar answer as I was writting mine.
Raymond's answer works in Python 2 also (see https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions, "General Error Handling" in "Questions") and has the advantage of outputing the error class too.