# How to convert a string, with functions inside, into a executable code in Python?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a .txt file that has the following text:

```
"np.sqrt(2)**2"
```

I can't get the answer to this mathematical equation because is a string, does anyone know how to convert that text to code (In python)? So when executing the script I will have the following output:

```
[In] np.sqrt(2)**2
[Out] 2
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python

Comment: you could use `eval` here. Usually, that's not a great solution, and is a security issue if the strings come from untrusted input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `eval()` method.
The return value is the result of the evaluated expression.

```
>>> x = 1
>>> eval('x + 1')
2
>>> eval('x')
1
```

Comment: Please read the proposed duplicate for the dangers of using `eval`