# convert a string written in python to execute inside a python. may also be a complete scirpt as string with user inputs in between

Tags: python

I have a string `'user = input("Hello World")'`. How can I execute the string to be able to run as a python command?

I am a new to python so I must have missed the basic syntax. please help me instead of routing me to another answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I execute a string containing Python code in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python)

Comment: Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: See [How much research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) and the [Question Checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use either of two `exec` or `eval` to run the string as python command based on your desired syntax or result

```
eval('user = input("Hello World")')
```

---

```
exec('user = input("Hello World")')
```

Visit [exec](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval) and [eval](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval) to learn more about them