# how to delete many tkinter entries together

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I have many tkinter entries named idn1 to idn5,instead of repeating the same
delete function for every entry I tried the following which went well with visual basic but not python:

```
def deleteme():
    
    idn = ""
    i = 1
    while True:
    
        idn ="idn"+str(i)+".delete(0,END)"
        
        i += 1
        idn
        
        if i == 6:
            break
    return True

root = Tk()

root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(460, 350))

idn1 = Entry(root).grid(row =0,column=1)

idn2 = Entry(root).grid(row =1,column=1)

idn3 = Entry(root).grid(row =2,column=1)

idn4 = Entry(root).grid(row =3,column=1)

idn5 = Entry(root).grid(row =4,column=1)

btn1 = Button(root,command = deleteme)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: [Does this help you?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python) Also, as an alternative: How about storing your objects in an array / list? Then you could just iterate over them.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this before but didn't work with me

Comment: keep widgets on list and then yoy need only `for`-loop to delete them . In current version you create strings like `"idn0.delete(0,END)"` but for Python it is only string, nothing more. It will not run it as command. You would need to use `eval("idn0.delete(0,END)")` but it is not preferred. There are other methods. Keep items on list or in dictionary and use `for`-loop

Answer (score 0):

You create strings like `"idn0.delete(0,END)"` but for Python it is only string, nothing more. It will not run it as command. You would need to use `eval("idn0.delete(0,END)")` to execute command in this string but `eval()` is not preferred method.

You should keep widgets on list or in dictionary and then you can use `for`-loop to delete all items.

---

But firt other very common mistake

Using

```
variable = Widget().grid()
```

you assign `None` to `variable` because `grid()`/`pack()`/`place()` return `None`

You have to do it in two steps

```
variable = Widget()
variable.grid()
```

---

Minimal working code

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- functions ---
 
def deleteme():
    
    for item in widgets:
        item.delete(0, 'end')
        
# --- main ---

widgets = []

root = tk.Tk()

for number in range(5):
    variable = tk.Entry(root)
    variable.grid(row=number, column=1)
    widgets.append(variable)
    
btn1 = tk.Button(root, text='Delete', command=deleteme) # PEP8: inside `()` use space after comma `,` but without spaces around `=`
btn1.grid(row=5, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

The same with dictionary

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- functions ---
 
def deleteme():
    
    for name, item in widgets.items():
        item.delete(0, 'end')
        
# --- main ---

widgets = {}

root = tk.Tk()

for number in range(1, 6):
    variable = tk.Entry(root)
    variable.grid(row=number, column=1)
    widgets[f"idn{number}"] = variable
    
btn1 = tk.Button(root, text='Delete', command=deleteme) # PEP8: inside `()` use space after comma `,` but without spaces around `=`
btn1.grid(row=5, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

---

Of course you can add widgets manually without `for`-loop but this it is long and boring so I skip some widgets. But even if I skip or add widgets I don't have to change code in `deleteme()`

```
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import *` is not preferred

# --- functions ---
 
def deleteme():
    
    for name, item in widgets.items():
        item.delete(0, 'end')
        
# --- main ---

widgets = {}

root = tk.Tk()

variable = tk.Entry(root)
variable.grid(row=0, column=1)
widgets["idn1"] = variable

# or 

widgets["idn2"] = tk.Entry(root)
widgets["idn2"].grid(row=1, column=1)
    
widgets["idn3"] = tk.Entry(root)
widgets["idn3"].grid(row=2, column=1)
    
# etc.    
    
btn1 = tk.Button(root, text='Delete', command=deleteme) # PEP8: inside `()` use space after comma `,` but without spaces around `=`
btn1.grid(row=5, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I found your answer very helpful, I appreciate your genuine help, it solved many problems in my app and gave me a great push, thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution, assuming your UI design supports it, is to put all of the entry widgets in a frame. You can then delete the frame and all of its children will automatically be deleted.

```
entry_frame = Frame(root)
idn1 = Entry(entry_frame).grid(row =0,column=1)
idn2 = Entry(entry_frame).grid(row =1,column=1)
idn3 = Entry(entry_frame).grid(row =2,column=1)
idn4 = Entry(entry_frame).grid(row =3,column=1)
idn5 = Entry(entry_frame).grid(row =4,column=1)
...
# this destroys the frame and all of its children
entry_frame.destroy()
```

If you can't do that or don't want to do that, the next best solution is to store the widgets in a list.

For example, you can create them in a list like so:

```
entries = []
for row in range(5):
    entry = Entry(root)
    entry.grid(row=row, column=1)
    entries.append(entry)
```

Of course, you don't have to create them in a loop. That works well if the widgets are largely identical. If each needs to be unique, create then individually and then append them to the list.

```
idn1 = Entry(root)
idn2 = Entry(root)
idn3 = Entry(root)
idn4 = Entry(root)
idn5 = Entry(root)
entries = [idn1, idn2, idn3, idn4, idn5]
```

Note: regardless of which method you choose, you must put the call to `grid` in a separate statement. The way you wrote your original code, all of your entry variables will be set to `None` since that's what `grid` returns.

However you create the list, you can delete them by iterating over the list:

```
for entry in entries:
    entry.destroy()
```

Comment: Thank you indeed, I also tried your suggestion and found it very useful in term  of uniquness of each widget.