# How to run multiple strings as source code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I'm solving some text2code problem for question-answering system and in the process I had the following question:
Is it possible to run strings of code as complete code by passing arguments from the original environment?
For example,I have these piece of code in str:

```
import module    
model=module(data,*args)
```

And from base environment I want to do:

```
#for example
args=[**some args**]
data=pd.DataFrame()
exec(string)(data=data,*args)
```

For obvious reasons, transferring the **data** object using *string.format()* will not work. Standard unpacking using * does not work either, although, perhaps, I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I execute a string containing Python code in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exec` can take 3 args: the string, globals var and locals var.

So you can do something like:

```py
exec(string, globals(), locals())
```

to pass all variable. It might be faster to only pass a subset of it:

```py
exec(string, None, {k: locals()[k] for k in ('data', 'args')})`
```

For single expression you can use `eval`:

```py
>>> i = 50
>>> eval("print(i)")
50
>>>
```

[How do I execute a string containing Python code in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python)

Comment: eval is only suitable for executing single expressions, it is not capable of executing a string as full source code:(

Comment: Yep,it works.It was only necessary to indicate the names of the arguments in the string itself, for some reason I did not think of this right away.Thanks!