# Is it possible run a string in Python

Tags: python

Is it possible to run a String text?

Example:

```
str = "print(2+4)"

Something(str)
```

Output:
`6`

Basically turning a string into code, and then running it.

Comment: While it's possible, it's generally not a good solution in basic applications unless you have no other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [exec](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/exec-in-python#:%7E:text=Exec%20function%20can%20dynamically%20execute,executed%20as%20a%20python%20statement.) as it can dynamically execute code of python programs.

```
strr = "print(2+4)"
exec(strr)

>> 6
```

I will not recommend you to use `exec` because:

- When you give your users the liberty to execute any piece of code with the Python exec() function, you give them a way to bend the rules.
- What if you have access to the os module in your session and they borrow a command from that to run? Say you have imported os in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Sure is, looks like your "Something" should be exec.

```
str = "print(2+4)"

exec(str)
```

Check out this previous question for more info:
[How do I execute a string containing Python code in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python)