# How can I execute a variable with the same 'text' as a string in python

Tags: python, string

I have a variable, `abc`, defined as `'batting_stats'` and want to run a line of code that is `'pyb.batting_stats(2020)'`. I want to use string syntax to create the line by joining abc with `'pyb.'` and `'(2020)'` and then run that line of code - how can I do this? I seem to be creating a larger string instance rather than a runnable line of code. Cheers!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I execute a string containing Python code in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python)

Comment: Or maybe this would be better: [How to access object attribute given string corresponding to name of that attribute](/q/2612610/4518341)

Answer (score 1):

You probably don't want to do this; it's possible, but in the vast majority of circumstances, it's a bad idea.

Options:

- If possible, try to rewrite the code so you don't need to look up by name at all; for instance, you could change the other code so that it stores `pyb.batting_stats` as a function rather than as a string

  ```
  abc = pyb.batting_stats  # note no brackets

  # later
  result = abc(2020)
  ```
- If you do need to look up by name, you can use `getattr`, like this:

  ```
  # At the top of the script
  ALLOWED_NAMES = ['batting_stats', ...]

  # in the code where you need it
  if abc not in ALLOWED_NAMES:
      raise ValueError("Invalid name passed: %s" % abc)
  result = getattr(pyb, abc)(2020)
  ```
- Probably a better way would be to use a dictionary as a dispatch table:

  ```
  dispatch_table = {
       'batting_stats': pyb.batting_stats,
       ...: ...,
  }
  result = dispatch_table[abc](2020)
  ```

  This automatically raises an exception if an unexpected name is passed.

  It also has the benefit that you can use a different string in the `abc` variable than the method name; for example, if you need to rename the function but maintain the names in an API or vice versa:

  ```
  dispatch_table = {
       'battingstats': pyb.batting_stats,  # legacy name
       'batting_stats': pyb.batting_stats,
       ...: ...,
  }
  result = dispatch_table[abc](2020)
  ```
- If you absolutely must run a piece of code from a string, you can use the `eval` or `exec` builtin functions; however, it's almost always a bad idea.

  Use of `eval` and `exec` is so frequently dangerous and insecure ([Common Weakness #95](https://cwe.mitre.org/data/definitions/95.html)) that it's better to avoid it altogether. Luckily, at least in Python, there's almost always an alternative; moreover, those alternatives are typically cleaner, more flexible, faster to run and easier to debug. Cases where there's no alternative are vanishingly rare.

Comment: Thanks that is really helpful! At the top of the comment when you said "You probably don't want to do this; it's possible, but in the vast majority of circumstances, it's a bad idea." was that specifically in reference to the 'eval' and 'exec' code? In general, if I wanted to standardize running methods with certain parameters and wanted to change only the method name (string), what would be the best practice here? Cheers! Really appreciate your help

Comment: Or rather, being new to coding, what is the best practice for standardizing running the line of code `pyb.XYZ(2020)` where XYZ changes each time run? Thanks again for the guidance

Comment: Best practice would probably be the "dispatch table" option, either written explicitly (like Django routes) or via decorators on each of the methods that may be run (like Flask routes)

Comment: I'm assuming that you're getting the method name because you're serving some sort of API; if it's coming from within the same program, probably better not to use a string at all

Comment: Thanks, it is actually not for an API (I am not sure what that is.) The use is for an internal program where pyb has different 'methods' (I think that's the name) that I want to call, and all with the same specifications. Basically pyb.batting_stats(2020) and a series of code after, then pyb.XXXX(2020) with the same series of code afterward to format.

Comment: In that case, don't use a string; just put the method itself in a variable, or otherwise rearrange it so you don't need to use a string

Comment: Ok that is super helpful, thank you so much! One other question, what if I want to create variables based on the input dictionary. So for example if the dictionary contains methods that produce a dataframe, I modify the dataframe, and then want to name and have part of the original variable name can that be done? To use the above example, it could be a variable called 'battingstatsMOD' which is based off the 'battingstats' key in the dictionary. I am not sure how to avoid using a string here to create the new variable name.

Comment: Why not put it in a new dictionary? `modified['battingstats'] = ...`

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure I see how that would work. Basically if the input dictionary contains {'xyz': corresponding method, etc} and I then want to create a variable output called xyz1, I could manipulate the 'xyz' string although then would not be sure how to define a variable based on that.

Comment: Instead of putting it in a variable called `xyz1`, put it in `results['xyz']`; creating local variables based on a string is usually a bad idea

Comment: Ok got it. For a different example, if I have a function that takes a dataframe as input  `pyth_wins(df)` and I want the name of the dataframe to create a new variable `total_DF` where DF references the original input name how would you do that? So basically total_ & the string of the input (name of that dataframe). This variable would equal a sum function applied to the dataframe after some manipulation. If I wanted to run `pyth_wins(2020)` it would create variable `total_2020` and if `pyth_wins(2021)`, `total_2021`. This would also be an output of the function, so reference able later on

Comment: Same thing, use a dictionary or some other data structure.

Comment: Right, but the key to the dataframe would be a string. So if I wanted to manipulate it and add to the end, then use that to create a new variable, can that be done? Not sure I am articulating this well at all, so please let me know if I am not being clear.

Comment: Just keep using dictionaries (or similar) for the rest of the program