# How to run python code directly on a webpage

Tags: python

My problem is as follows:
I have written a python code, and I need to run it on a web page.Basically I need that whatever is on the console should be displayed as it is.

I have no experience in web development and similar libraries, and I need to get this done in a short time. Kindly tell how should I proceed?

Note: I might be plotting some graphs also. It would be great if they could be displayed all at once(sequentially) on the website

Answer (score 2):

https://brython.info/
https://skulpt.org/
https://pyodide.org/en/stable/

There are multiple python implementation on browser, some are webassemble some are javascript.

Is it a good idea to run python on browser *as a replacement for javascript* in 2022? No it is not, learn javascript. No in-browser python implementation can race with javascript as of today and most probably ever.

Comment: WASM is definitely a game changer.

Answer (score -1):

You **Can't** execute **Python-Code** *directly* inside a webbrowser - however, you could for instance create a basic **IDE** in **HTML & JS**, send code written by a user on the page to a **Server**, which would then run the code and send the **results back to the client-page**.

**Unfortunately**, such a project is quite ambitious and complicated, especially when **Security & Stability** are of mayor concern, as executing client-code is a very dangerous measure indeed, and requires expertise in **Virtualization Techniques & Software**.

Another Method could be to use a **public API**, which allows you to run Python code and fetch the results back. The procedure would be exactly the same as with the previous idea in terms of creating the web-client, but the **heavy-lifting** - which is actually executing the **Python-code**, would be taken care of for you.

As you can see, there is no concrete answer to this question, only suggestions.

A few useful links below:

https://docs.docker.com/

https://appdividend.com/2022/01/18/best-python-online-ide/

https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/programmer-browser-ides/

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=og9Gaj1Hzag

[How do I execute a string containing Python code in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python)

Comment: This is incorrect. You definitely *can* run python in browser. Should you is a different question but you definitely can.

Comment: @IşıkKaplan I don't  know of any browser with an embedded Python-Interpreter, could you name an example?

Comment: There doesn't have to be an embedded interpreter for you to be able to run python. Do checkout my answer. It has several links.

Comment: @IşıkKaplan Still no "real" CPython, ports to WebAssembly or JS emulations etc. Those are fine when Performance is not of concern, but (I may be wrong) I highly doubt that those will perform even close to as well as the real thing.

Comment: What does "real" mean? Just because the implementation is written in wasm, doesn't make it any less python.

Comment: By your logic, pypy is also not python because it is not cpython, cpython is a c implementation, granted the reference implementation, but an implementation of the rules of the language. Python doesn't mean cpython.

Comment: What's the Python specification say about built in functions like `open`, for example? Are they optional? A Wasm or JS implementation that runs in the browser would be presumably be sandboxed and not have full access to the filesystem.