# How to create automatic variables for large number of values in list. For ex. list with 50 values how can we assign values to 50 different variables

Tags: python, list, variables, automatic-ref-counting

How can we assign large number of different variables to large number of list values for example. x1, x2, x3 upto xn.

Comment: Rather than trying to create variable names dynamically, use a dictionary where the keys are (effectively) the variable "names" with associated values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `exec` which evaluates a string at runtime and then executes it as you were typing it. Combine it with the `format` specifier and the string concatenations and you have>

```
s = ""
for i in range(0,10):
    s+="x{0} = mylist[{0}]\n".format(i)

mylist = [i*i for i in range(10)]
exec(s)
```

which is equivalent to typing manually:

```
x0 = mylist[0]
x1 = mylist[1]
x2 = mylist[2]
x3 = mylist[3]
x4 = mylist[4]
x5 = mylist[5]
x6 = mylist[6]
x7 = mylist[7]
x8 = mylist[8]
x9 = mylist[9]
```

You can then test it this way:

```
p = ""
for i in range(10):
    p+="print(\"x{0} = \",x{0})\n".format(i)
exec(p)
```

Which gives you:

```
x0 =  0
x1 =  1
x2 =  4
x3 =  9
x4 =  16
x5 =  25
x6 =  36
x7 =  49
x8 =  64
x9 =  81
```

However, quoting [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python)

> the first step should be to ask yourself if you really need to. Executing code should generally be the position of last resort: It's slow, ugly and dangerous if it can contain user-entered code. You should always look at alternatives first, such as higher order functions, to see if these can better meet your needs.