# How do I execute a string containing Python, without creating a new file or using "os" module?

Tags: python

How do I execute a string containing Python, without creating a new file, **using excec()** or using "os" module?

I've seen the similiar question, but the answeres always kind of created some "new file"(for example created something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48054410/19581791)), or went out of the current code, but i want it to stay inside the code and execute it.

Example:

```
string_base64 = "eCA9ICJoZWxsbyBmZWxsb3ciCgoKcHJpbnQoeCkKeCA9ICJoZWxsbyBmZWxsb3ciCgoKcHJpbnQoeCkKeCA9ICJoZWxsbyBmZWxsb3ciCgoKcHJpbnQoeCkKeCA9ICJoZWxsbyBmZWxsb3ciCgoKcHJpbnQoeCk="
```

This b64 code has inside it strings and commands (+ For example imports) and it needs to run in the current file, without using exec() or modules

**[This Thread and the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python), didn't answer the question!**

Comment: I think you'll have to provide an example of how to decode your sample string, and also why `exec()` doesn't work for you.  `exec()` is the canonical way to do this; stating that you can't use makes this seem like an X/Y problem.

Comment: Does this need to run in some sort of limited environment where `exec` isn't available? If so, you may be out of luck. Some things are still possible with `eval` and things like `getattr`, but that's highly dependent on what your code needs to do. And no built-in solution is going to decrypt your code for you, you're still going to have to do that. Like NicholasM, I feel like we're missing something important here... or possibly you are. It's impossible to tell so far.

Comment: A straightforward [MRE] would certainly help. And please explain what about `exec` doesn't "stay inside the code and execute it" for your purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Buildin `exec` function seems to be doing exactly what you want:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec