# Is there a way to execute a python function after every statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a python function and I want it to be executed after every statement that is executed anyway. Is there a way to do it without manually writing it under every statement?

Comment: Why do you want this? It sounds like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: Is this for debugging purposes?

Comment: "Line of code" isn't really a useful "chunk" of Python. Your code consists of a series of *statements*, each of which could span multiple lines.

Comment: @chepner isn't a _statement_ usually separated from another using a line break? I guess you're right that I could separate my statement with a backslash but I presumed it was pretty obvious - will edit my question regardless.

Comment: Usually, but not always. `x = 1; y = 2` is a single line with two statements. (Only *simple* statements can be separated by a `;` on a single line.) But there are also compound statements (`if`, `while`, etc) that are single statements that can (and usually do) span multiple lines.

Comment: I suppose, yea. Do you know how this could be achieved?

Comment: I think this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of something that leans towards what you want (there are probably better/cleaner ways)

```
mycode= '''
print("Hello World :)")

a = 5
x = a+2

print(a, x)
'''

def my_func():
    print("Test".center(30,"-"))

for line in mycode.splitlines():
    if not line.strip(): continue # skips empty lines
    exec(line)
    my_func()
```