# How to transfer quoted values from an excel sheet to a list without adding single quotes (using openpyxl or pandas)

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, list, openpyxl

Let's say I have these values in an excel sheet:

`"Hello!"

"Testing!"

"My name is " + random.choice(random_names) + "."

"Goodbye!'`

I already have the random_names list earlier in my program:

`random_names = ["Harry", "Sam", "Albert"]`

How can I transfer these values from an excel sheet into a python list? When I try doing it using openpyxl:

```
(for phrase_cell in phrase_sheet['A']: 
    random_phrases_list.append(phrase_cell.value)
```

I get a list that looks like this when printed:

`['"Hello!"', '"Testing!"', '"My name is " + random.choice(random_names) + "."', '"Goodbye!"']`

This doesn't work, because when I print the 3rd (i=2) value of the list, this is the output:

`"My name is " + random.choice(random_names) + "."`

If I remove the quotes from my excel sheet, I get a list that looks like this:

`['Hello!', 'Testing!', 'My name is + random.choice(random_names) + .', 'Goodbye!']`

And when I print the 3rd value of the list, this is the output:

`My name is + random.choice(random_names) + .`

**Any way I can remove the single quotes that surround each value of the list so that my list would look like this:**

`["Hello!", "Testing!", "My name is " + random.choice(random_names) + ".", "Goodbye!"]`

**And if I printed the 3rd value of this list it would be this (for example):**

`My name is Albert.`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python

Comment: [This comment is very relevant however](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701802/how-do-i-execute-a-string-containing-python-code-in-python#comment514609_701802).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will never get that desired output. The reason being is that the values from excel are string values and random.choice() is a python function. Your third value '"My name is " + random.choice(random_names) + "."' is a string value that has nothing to do with python. Your issues has nothing to do with the quotations.

One possible solution would be to append your function to the random_phrases_list. Here is what I believe what you were trying to do:

```
import random
random_names = ['Harry', 'Sam', 'Albert']

random_phrases_list = ['Hello!', 'Testing!', 'Goodbye!']

def my_name_is_function():
    name = random.choice(random_names)
    return 'My name is ' + name + '.'

random_phrases_list.append(my_name_is_function)

print(random_phrases_list[3]())
My name is Harry.
```