# Reading substring logic from csv file in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, pycharm, config

I need to derive a new column from existing column in dataframe. this logic will be different for different runs.
For this, I have decided to have a config file so that logic can be updated in config file easily.

logic_Entry in config file:

```
df['col1'].str[1:4]
```

used in code like below:

```
df['col2']= logic_Entry
```

but when I check the output in col2 it just puts the logic as a literal, so in this example I get value as df['col1'].str[1:4] for all records.

I was expecting it to instead evaluate this logic and put substring of `col1` in this new column (`col2`).

Can someone please suggest what am I missing?

Comment: *I was expecting it to instead evaluate this logic* : You are probably looking for `eval()`. This executes whatever python code you put inside a string. But you should not do this approach. You have an XY problem with how you are using your config file. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/701802/22390653) for context.

Comment: Do you really need to be able to put arbitrary logic in the config file? Or could you use something like `col=col1` and `substring=1:4`